# Why does adb exec-out behave differently in powershell?

Tags: powershell, adb

I'm using `ADB exec-out screencap -p > temp.png` in a batch script, and it outputs a regular .png file whereas the exact same syntax in powershell is giving me a corrupted .png file that is not readable. Any idea how to correct this in powershell?

ADB version 1.0.40, powershell version 1.0

Comment: In short: PowerShell has no support for sending raw output from external programs to files; you need to call via `cmd /c`: `cmd /c 'ADB exec-out screencap -p > temp.png'`. See the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375) for background information.