# Why does the Windows type command change data when invoked via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I had tried to `type File.jpg | ncat 192.168.0.2 3333` a file from Windows to Linux but the file was not the same. It was slightly larger and a hex editor showed most bytes were the same, with some changes and insertions scattered throughout.

I tried `type C:\Path\File.jpg > C:\PathFile1.jpg` and was surprised to obtain a file roughly twice the size of the original, with `00` inserted between the original file's hex values that mostly remained unaltered, with a few alterations and insertions.

I had executed those commands in Powershell. Then I tried the same commands using the old `cmd.exe` command prompt, and they worked!

This behavour is a surprise and I couldn't find any information on it. What's going on with Powershell?

Comment: In short: As of PowerShell 7.2, output from external programs is invariably decoded _as text_ before further processing, which means that _raw byte output_ can neither be passed on via `|` nor  captured with `>`. See the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59110563/45375) for details. The workaround is to call your external program via `cmd /c` (Windows) / `sh -c` (Unix-like platforms) and use _their_ `|` and `>` operators.

Comment: P.S: `type` in PowerShell (on Windows) is a built-in alias of the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) cmdlet.