# How can tshark and powershell redirection create a bytecode textfile?

Tags: python, powershell, encoding, wireshark

Okay so this is actually a problem I have been able to fix, but I still do not understand why the problem existed in the first place.

I have been using tshark on network traffic with the intention of creating a txt or csv file containing key information I can use for machine learning. At first glance the file looked perfectly fine and exactly how I imagined. However, in python I notice some strange inital characters and when applying the split operator, suddenly I am working on bytecode.

My powershell script initially looked like this:

```
$src = "G:\...\train_data\"
$dst = $src+"tsharked\"
Write-Output $dst

Get-ChildItem $src -Filter *.pcap | 
Foreach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
    $filename=$_.BaseName
    tshark -r $_.FullName -T fields -E separator="," -E quote=n -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e tcp.len -e frame.time_relative -e frame.time_delta > $dst$filename.txt
}
```

Now I try to read this file in my jupyter notebook

```
directory = "G://.../train_data/tsharked/"
file = open(directory+"example.txt", "r")
for line in file.readlines():
    print(line)
    words = line.split(",")
    print(words)
    break
```

The result looks like this

```
ÿþ134.169.109.51,134.169.109.25,543,0.000000000,0.000000000

['ÿþ1\x003\x004\x00.\x001\x006\x009\x00.\x001\x000\x009\x00.\x005\x001\x00', '\x001\x003\x004\x00.\x001\x006\x009\x00.\x001\x000\x009\x00.\x002\x005\x00', '\x005\x004\x003\x00', '\x000\x00.\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x00', '\x000\x00.\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x000\x00\n']
```

When I opened the textfile in Editor, the special characters **ÿþ** did not appear. This is the first time I see them. What do they even mean here?
Anyhow I managed to fix this only by removing the output redirection in my powershell script.

```
$src = "G:\...\train_data\"
$dst = $src+"tsharked\"
Write-Output $dst

Get-ChildItem $src -Filter *.pcap | 
Foreach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
    $filename=$_.BaseName
    $out = tshark -r $_.FullName -T fields -E separator="," -E quote=n -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e tcp.len -e frame.time_relative -e frame.time_delta
    Set-Content -Path $dst$filename.txt -Value $out
}
```

And this is where I am asking myself the question of how it is possible that the output redirection in powershell has managed to write some kind of byte output? In my understanding this is simply a redirection of the console output, hence the name. How can this be anything but a String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **As of PowerShell 7.2, output from external programs is invariably decoded *as text* before further processing**, which means that *raw (byte) output* can neither be passed on via `|` nor  captured with `>`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59110563/45375) for details.
- **PowerShell's `>` redirection operator is effectively an alias of [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file)**, and *its* default character encoding therefore applies.

In *Windows PowerShell*, `Out-File` defaults to "Unicode" encoding, i.e. [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)LE:

- This encoding uses a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (byte-order mark), whose bytes, if interpreted individually as ANSI (Windows-1252) bytes, render as `ÿþ`), and it represents most characters as *two*-byte sequences,<sup>[1]</sup> which in the case of most characters in the Windows-1252 character set (which itself is a superset of ASCII) means that the *second* byte in each sequence is a `NUL` (`0x0` byte) - this is what you're seeing.

Fortunately, in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, all file-processing cmdlets now *consistently* default to (BOM-less) UTF-8.

To use a different encoding, either call `Out-File` explicitly and use its `-Encoding` parameter, or - as you have done, and as is generally preferable for the sake of performance when dealing with data that already is *text*  - use [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content).

---

<sup>[1] *At least* two bytes are needed per character; for characters outside the so-called [BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), a *pair* of two-byte sequences is needed.</sup>