# Python standard IO under Windows PowerShell and CMD

Tags: python, powershell, input, cmd, standards

I have the following two-line Python (v. 3.10.7) program "stdin.py":

```
    import sys
    print(sys.stdin.read())
```

and the following one-line text file "ansi.txt"  (CP1252 encoding) containing:

```
    ‘I am well’ he said.
```

Note that the open and close quotes are `0x91` and `0x92`, respectively. In Windows-10 cmd mode the behavior of the Python code is as expected:

```
    python stdin.py < ansi.txt  # --> ‘I am well’ he said.
```

On the other hand in Windows Powershell:

```
    cat .\ansi.txt | python .\stdin.py  # --> ?I am well? he said.
```

Apparently the CP1252 characters  are seen as non-printable characters in the
combination Python/PowerShell. If I replace in "stdin.py" the standard input by file input, Python prints correctly the CP1252 quote characters to screen. PowerShell by itself recognizes and prints correctly `0x91` and `0x92`.

Questions: can somebody explain to me why cmd works differently than PowerShell in combination with Python? Why doesn't Python recognize the CP1252 quote characters  `0x91` and `0x92` when they are piped into it by PowerShell?

Comment: Are you actually using "Windows PowerShell" or "PowerShell 7"? If the latter, you should be able to use `-Encoding CP1252` to read it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Use the **[`$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding)**:

- In *Windows PowerShell*:

```
# Using the system's legacy ANSI code page, as Python does by default.
# NOTE: The & { ... } enclosure isn't strictly necessary, but 
#       ensures that the $OutputEncoding change is only temporary,
#       by limiting to the child scope that the enclosure cretes.
& {
 $OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default
 "‘I am well’ he said." | python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.read())'
}

# Using UTF-8 instead, which is generally preferable.
# Note the `-X utf8` option (Python 3.7+)
& {
 $OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
 "‘I am well’ he said." | python -X utf8 -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.read())'
}
```

- In [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md):

```
# Using the system's legacy ANSI code page, as Python does by default.
# Note: In PowerShell (Core) / .NET 5+,
#       [System.Text.Encoding]::Default` now reports UTF-8, 
#       not the active ANSI encoding.
& {
 $OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding([cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage)
 "‘I am well’ he said." | python -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.read())'
}

# Using UTF-8 instead, which is generally preferable.
# Note the `-X utf8` option (Python 3.7+)
# NO need to set $OutputEncoding, as it now *defaults* to UTF-8
"‘I am well’ he said." | python -X utf8 -c 'import sys; print(sys.stdin.read())'
```

Note:

- **[`$OutputEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding)** controls what **encoding is used to send data TO external programs** via the pipeline (to stdin). It defaults to ASCII(!) in *Windows PowerShell*, and UTF-8 in *PowerShell (Core)*.
- **[`[Console]::OutputEncoding`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Console.OutputEncoding)** controls **how data received FROM external programs (via stdout) is decoded**. It defaults to the console's active code page, which in turn defaults to the system's legacy OEM code page, such as `437` on US-English systems).

  - Note that this implies that **if you want to *receive* data from a `python` call for *programmatic processing***, you **must (temporarily) set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` too** - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78227364/45375).

That these two encodings are *not* aligned by default is unfortunate; while *Windows PowerShell* will see no more changes, there is hope for *PowerShell (Core)*: it would make sense to have it default *consistently* to UTF-8:

- [GitHub issue #7233](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7233) suggests at least defaulting the shortcut files that launch PowerShell to UTF-8 (code page `65001`); [GitHub issue #14945](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14945) more generally discusses the problematic mismatch.
- **In *Windows 10 and above*, there is an option to switch to UTF-8 *system-wide***, which then makes both the OEM and ANSI code pages default to UTF-8 (`65001`); however, **this has *far-reaching consequences*** and is still labeled as being *in beta* as of Windows 11 - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375).

---

##### Background information:

It is the **[`$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding)** that determines what character encoding PowerShell uses to send data (invariably *text*, as of PowerShell 7.3) to an *external program* via the pipeline.

- Note that this even  applies when data is read *from a file*: **PowerShell, as of v7.3, never sends *raw bytes* through the pipeline: it reads the content into .NET strings *first* and then *re-encodes* them** based on `$OutputEncoding` on sending them through the pipeline to an external program.
- Therefore, **what encoding your `ansi.txt` input file uses is ultimately irrelevant, as long as PowerShell decodes it correctly** when reading it into .NET strings (which are internally composed of UTF-16 code units).
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375) for more information.

Thus, **the character encoding stored in `$OutputEncoding` must match the encoding that the target program expects**.

*By default* the encoding in `$OutputEncoding` is *unrelated* to the encoding implied by the console's active code page (which itself defaults to the system's legacy OEM code page, such as [`437`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) on US-English systems), which is what at least legacy console applications tend to use; however, Python does *not*, and uses the legacy *ANSI* code page; other modern CLIs, notably Node.js' `node.exe`, always use UTF-8.

While `$OutputEncoding`'s default in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) is now UTF-8, *Windows PowerShell*'s default is, regrettably, ASCII(!), which means that non-ASCII characters get "lossily" transliterated to *verbatim* ASCII `?` characters, which is what you saw.

Therefore, you must (temporarily) set `$OutputEncoding` to the encoding that Python expects and/or ask it use UTF-8 instead.

Comment: Your answer is great and stimulates me to a much deeper  study of PowerShell. So far I saw PS as a replacement to CMD, but I realize now that there is much more to learn. Thank you again for your extensive answer. I came across this problem because I have some old text files  coded in CP1252 that I wanted to inspect by  Python scripts.