# non-ASCII characters in CLI output in powershell script

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface

How can I retrieve users with non-latin names from this output?

```
.\Pacli.exe USERSLIST INCLUDESUBLOCATIONS=YES output`(name`, enclose`, type`) > users.txt
```

This saves and recalls the non-latin characters as `?` or `�` even with Get-Content -Encoding UTF8.

I tried to set

```
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```

before this command but got the same result.

Comment: found it, it's [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("Windows-1252") Thank you very much @mklement0! This changes the encoding only for the current .ps1 script, right?

Comment: no, the change persists for the remainder of the session, so it's best to restore the original value of `[Console]::OutputEncoding` after the `.\Pacli.exe` call - please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Use the code at the bottom to temporarily change `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to match `PACLI.exe`'s nonstandard output encoding, which appears to be *ANSI*, to ensure that its output is decoded correctly.

---

Per your own feedback, it turns out that [`PACLI.exe`](https://docs.cyberark.com/pam-self-hosted/latest/en/Content/PACLI/Introduction.htm) exhibits *nonstandard behavior* and outputs [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)-encoded text.

- Note that the specific code page used on a given system may be driven more abstractly by the legacy *ANSI* code page associated with that system's legacy *system locale* (aka language for non-Unicode programs). This is the - also nonstandard - behavior that *Python* exhibits, for instance.

  - E.g., on a US English machine the ANSI code page would be `1252` (Windows-1252), but on a Russian machine it would be `1251` ([Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251)).
- The solution below assumes that `PACLI.exe` too exhibits this ANSI-code-page-dependent behavior, so it uses the following to retrieve the current machine's ANSI code page, whatever it may be; if you know that `PACLI.exe` *hard-codes* use of `1252`, specifically, replace the expression with verbatim `1252`:

  ```bash
  [int] (Get-ItemPropertyValue HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage ACP)
  ```

---

##### Capturing output from external programs that use nonstandard character encodings:

- It is a general requirement that the **character encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding` must match the actual encoding used in the output from an *external program***, because PowerShell uses the former to decode the latter.

  - Note:

    - This applies whenever PowerShell *captures* the output, such as in a *variable* or as part of an expression, or by relaying it to another command *via the pipeline*.
    - There is a notable exception with respect to `>`, the [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) operator in *PowerShell (Core) 7.4+*: when applied to an *external program*, the *raw output bytes* are *passed through* to the target file. To instead capture the output and save it with a *different* encoding, use the pipeline and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content).
  - The **encoding used for sending data *to* an external program via the *pipeline*** is stored in the [**`$OutputEncoding`** preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding), which - unfortunately - defaults to ASCII(!) in _Windows PowerShell, and to UTF-8 in [*PowerShell (Core) 7*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) (which is preferable to ASCII, but inconsistent with the `[Console]::OutputEncoding` value - see [GitHub issue #7233](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7233)).

    - Again, there is an exception in PowerShell 7.4+: if the pipeline input is *also* provided by an *external program*, the raw bytes are passed through.
- *Standard* behavior of console applications would be to respect the current console's output code page, as reflected in the encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, in which case *no* extra effort is needed to properly decode and capture output.

  - Console windows / Windows Terminal tabs default to the legacy *OEM* code page associated with a given machine's system locale, such as [`CP437`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) on US-English systems.
- It is the limitations of the *single-byte*<sup>[1]</sup> OEM code pages - which limits what you can output to *256* characters that increasingly cause modern CLIs to output [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), as it is capable of encoding *all Unicode characters*. `node.exe`, the Node.Js CLI, is one example. Others allow UTF-8 *opt-in*, via command-line options or environment variables.
- The `PACLI.exe` and Python behavior of choosing the *ANSI* code page for their nonstandard encoding is unfortunate, because ANSI code pages are *single-byte*<sup>[1]</sup> too, and therefore don't solve the problem of limited character repertoire.
- There is a *system-wide* solution that makes *most* programs behave properly without extra effort; however - it has *far-reaching consequences* and *can change the behavior of existing scripts in undesired ways*.

  - Assuming you have administrative privileges, you can set the legacy system locale to *UTF-8*, which sets *both* the OEM and the ANSI code page to `65001`, the UTF-8 code page. For details and the discussion of the far-reaching consequences, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375).
  - Note that this solution won't help with Windows CLIs such as `sfc.exe` and `wsl.exe`, which (situationally) output [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)LE; unless such CLIs offer UTF-8 *opt-in* (e.g. WSL's `$env:WSL_UTF8=1`), you still need to temporarily modify `[Console]::OutputEncoding`, as shown below.
- Otherwise, **you'll need to *temporarily* change `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to match a nonstandard CLI's output encoding**, as shown below. That is, save the current value of `[Console]::OutputEncoding` before changing it, and restore it afterwards, to avoid affecting subsequent calls to (standard) external (console) applications (by default, because changing `[Console]::OutputEncoding` affects the *console window*, it stays in effect for the remainder of the session).

**Capturing output from a CLI that outputs ANSI**, like (presumably) `PACLI.exe` and Python, using your specific `PACLI.exe` call:

```bash
& {
  # Temporarily change the expected output encoding to ANSI.
  $prevEnc = [Console]::OutputEncoding
  [Console]::OutputEncoding = 
    [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(
      [int] (Get-ItemPropertyValue HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage ACP)
    )

  try {

   .\Pacli.exe USERSLIST INCLUDESUBLOCATIONS=YES output`(name`, enclose`, type`) |
      Set-Content -Encoding utf8 users.txt

  } finally {

    # Restore the original encoding.
    [Console]::OutputEncoding = $prevEnc

  }
}
```

- For UTF-8, use `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()`
- Note that `> users.txt` was deliberately replaced with `| Set-Content -Encoding utf8 users.txt`, to predictably generate a UTF-8 output file, in both PowerShell editions - although in *Windows PowerShell* the file will have a *BOM*.<sup>[2]</sup>

  - That is, the use of the *pipeline* with a file-saving command ensures that *decoding into .NET strings* of the external-program output takes place first, with the file-saving command then using *its* default encoding or the encoding specified via `-Encoding`. This in effect allows you to *transcode* the output; in the case at hand, ANSI output turns into UTF-8 output.
  - In Windows PowerShell and PowerShell 7 *up to 7.3.x*, the `>` operator too exhibits this behavior, where it is in effect an alias of piping to [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) using *the latter's default encoding*, which is UTF-16LE ("Unicode") in Windows PowerShell, and (BOM-less) UTF-8 in PowerShell 7.3-
  - As noted above, with respect to *external programs* `>` in PowerShell *7.4+* now behaves differently, and captures the *raw byte output* in the target file; that is, with `> users.txt` the above would create an *ANSI* file.

---

<sup>[1] Except in [CJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters) system locales.</sup>

<sup>[2] Unfortunately, *workarounds* are required to create *BOM-less* UTF-8 files in Windows PowerShell (which PowerShell 7 creates *by default*) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375).</sup>