# Equivalent of Powershell `Out-File` for Bash

Tags: bash, powershell

`echo "C:\tools\somepath\toabinary\bin" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_PATH -Encoding utf8 -Append`

How can I achieve the results this Powershell commmand gives using Bash? Unfortunately I can barely find something on the net.

This is meant to be used in a Github action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash and POSIX-compatible shells in general have no explicit *command* for saving stdout data to a file; they have [*redirection operators*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) `>` and `>>` (also supported analogously in PowerShell), which correspond to [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) and `Out-File -Append`, respectively:

```bash
# Bash equivalent of your command.
echo "C:\tools\somepath\toabinary\bin" >> "$GITHUB_PATH"
```

- The character encoding is implied by the `LC_CTYPE` setting, as reported by `locale`, and it is almost always UTF-8 on modern Unix-like platforms.
- In POSIX-compatible shells - unlike in PowerShell - both shell-only and environment variables are referenced with the *same* notation, using symbol `$` before the variable name. Therefore, environment variable `GITHUB_PATH` must be referenced as `$GITHUB_PATH`.
- As [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) points out - unlike in PowerShell - it is best to enclose variables in double quotes (`"..."`) to ensure that their value is used as-is, without being subject to the so-called [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html), notably [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html), where unquoted values with embedded spaces become *multiple* arguments.

Note a fundamental difference between POSIX-compatible shells and PowerShell with respect to the data flowing through pipelines (`|`) / getting redirected with `>` and `>>`:

- In POSIX-compatible shells, these operators serve as *raw byte conduits*, and the data may or may not represent *text*.
- In PowerShell, they are conduits for *.NET objects*, which in the case of *external programs* invariably means interpretation as *lines of text*, as of PowerShell 7.3.2 - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375) for background information.