# Windows PowerShell variable value directly into file on ftp server

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to save variable value(s) to my ftp server directly from memory, without creating a local file. Variable can be single line or multi line.

For example:

```
PowerShell C:\> $cm = tasklist /S localhost /FO LIST
PowerShell C:\> $cm

............
............
............
.....list of tasks
...etc...

PowerShell C:\> $session_token = "bG9uZyBzZXNzaW9uIHRva2VubG9uZyBzZXNzaW9uIHRva2VubG9uZ"
```

I know how to create a file with tasklist output and upload to ftp server every 10 seconds (scheduled task), but i need to do it without file creation. Any solutions?

Comment: I'm not a server guy but one possibility (you can google it) is to use powershell to create a RAM Disk, store your file there then upload it to your FTP server. No local storage required.

Answer (score 0):

Recent Windows versions ship with `curl` (`C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe`).

Per the [manual](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html), the `--upload-file` (`-T`) option accepts `-` in lieu of a local file path, in which case its uses the data received *via stdin* as the file content to upload.

Therefore, something like the following should work (untested):

```bash
# Note: Be sure to use curl.exe, i.e *with extension ".exe"* in Windows PowerShell.
tasklist /S localhost /FO LIST | 
  curl.exe --upload-file - ftp://ftp.example.com/dir/path/remote-file
```

The caveat is that from PowerShell, as of version 7.3.3, that only works with *text* data, which is encoded based on the [`$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding).

If you have *binary* data to send, such as the output from an *external program*, call via `cmd /c`, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375).