# How to pipe without waiting for first command to finish?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pipe output logs to another script for processing. However, if I undestand [this issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1947) correctly, powershell waits for first command to finish before sending output to second command.

For example, this works as expected (script receives "hi"), since `echo` finishes quickly:

```
echo "hi" | python script.py
```

While in this one (`caddy` is webserver, so it doesn't finish) caddy's stdout never reaches script's stdin:

```
caddy run | python script.py
```

Is it possible to forward output of first command to second asynchronously, without waiting for first to finish?

--

Edit: minimal example

```py
# output.py

from time import sleep

while True:
    print("SENDING")
    sleep(1)
```

```py
# onetime.py

print("SENDING")
```

```py
# input.py
import sys

while True:
    for line in sys.stdin:
        print(f"Received: {line}")
```

This works (prints to stdout `Received: SENDING`):

```
python onetime.py | python input.py
```

This doesn't work (nothing is printed):

```
python output.py | python input.py
```

Comment: You say `caddy run` "never sends output", so what exactly is that that you want "forwarded" to the python script?

Comment: Maybe I was unclear - caddy sends output every few seconds (when request arrives). However script never receives it as input (pipe doesn't forward it).

Comment: As per @Mathias' commend, `caddy` isn't native PowerShell but an external command that isn't written according the [Write Single Records to the Pipeline (SC03)](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines#write-single-records-to-the-pipeline-sc03) of the PowerShell Strongly Encouraged Development Guidelines.

Comment: @iRon so is there any workaround for external commands, given that not all software can be modified inhouse? Is there some way to wrap it into better behaved script?

Comment: @iRon, those guidelines don't apply to _external (native) programs_, which cannot be expected to abide by these rules. PowerShell treats the _lines_ of an external program's stdout output as the objects to send through the pipeline, and - due to a serious design limitation - this doesn't happen in a _streaming_ manner in _Windows PowerShell_ when the _consumer_ is an external program, something that has fortunately been fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed:

- In ***Windows PowerShell*,** when **piping *to an external program***, the **input command's output is *unexpectedly***:

  - *collected in full* in memory *first*
  - and the collected output is passed on via the pipeline only *after the input command has exited*.
- Fortunately, this has been **fixed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, where an input command's output is now *streamed*, *line by line*, as the lines become available, as usual. (This is also how it works in Windows PowerShell if the receiving command is a *PowerShell* command.)

A simple **example**:

- Note that it doesn't matter whether the *input-providing* command is a PowerShell command or an external program - what matters is that the *receiving* command is an external program
- The example input command outputs 3 numbers, one at a time, and waits 1 second after each, and finally  waits for the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before exiting.
  The receiving command, `findstr.exe .`, simply echoes each number.

```bash
# In Windows PowerShell:
#   3 seconds elapse without anything getting printed, because PowerShell
#   is collecting the output first.
#   Then the user is prompted to press Enter.
#   Only if and when the user does so do the numbers print.
# In PowerShell 7+:
#   The numbers print as they are being emitted by the ForEach-Object call, and
#   only then is the user prompted to press Enter.
1..3 | ForEach-Object { $_; sleep 1 } -end { pause } | findstr.exe .
```

---

**Workaround**:

**Call via `cmd.exe`'s CLI**, (`cmd /c`), because `cmd.exe`'s pipeline behaves as expected (on ***Unix*-like platforms**, analogously use **`sh -c`**):

```bash
cmd /c 'caddy run | python script.py'
```

In fact:

- `cmd.exe`'s (`/bin/sh`'s) pipeline is a *raw byte conduit*, unlike PowerShell's pipeline, which as of v7.3.4 "speaks only text"
- Therefore, the above workaround is also needed in cases where sending raw byte data to / between external programs / to a file is necessary - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375).