# Character encoding problem when importing SQL with DBForge and PowerShell into MySQL

Tags: mysql, powershell, cmd, character-encoding, dbforge

I have a problem with MySQL and/or DBforge.

I would like to import a schema using an .sql file that DBforge generated for me by comparing 2 databases.

The file DBforge created for me contains characters with accents (éèêàâ...), so far nothing abnormal, I'm French and the stored procedures I need to import are written in French.

However, when I want to execute this .sql file in my database in a PowerShell :

```bash
Get-Content $SQLfile -Encoding UTF8 | 
     mysql --password=$($target.password) -h $($target.host) -P $($target.port) -u $($target.user) --default-character-set utf8mb4 -f -D $db 2> $tempErrorFile
```

All special characters are replaced by `?` despite the fact that my .sql file is in UTF8 and has accents.

Here's my call to dbforge to generate the .sql file for me (although I doubt that's where the problem is):

```bash
&$($DBFORGE_PATH + 'dbforgemysql.com') /schemacompare /source connection:$SOURCE_LINE /target connection:$TARGET_LINE /ExcludeComments:Yes /ExcludeDependencies:Yes /IncludeUseDatabase:Yes /filter:$selectedFilter /sync:$SQL_DBFORGE /log:$LOG_DBFORGE_FILE
```

Here is my call to mysql with the file generated by dbforge :

```bash
&cmd /c "mysql --password=$($target.password) -h $($target.host) -P $($target.port) -u $($target.user) --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -f -D $db < $SQLfile 2> $tempErrorFile"
```

I tried another way:

```bash
Get-Content $SQLfile -Encoding UTF8 | 
    mysql --password=$($target.password) -h $($target.host) -P $($target.port) -u $($target.user) --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -f -D $db 2> $tempErrorFile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Execute `$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()` before your command to ensure that Windows PowerShell sends UTF-8 to `mysql`:

  ```bash
  $OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()

  Get-Content $SQLfile -Encoding UTF8 | 
    mysql --password=$($target.password) -h $target.host -P $target.port -u $target.user --default-character-set utf8mb4 -f -D $db 2> $tempErrorFile
  ```
- The reason that your `cmd` solution worked is that its `<` and `>` redirection operators function as *raw byte conduits*. Therefore, your input file's content was (correctly) passed as-is to `mysql`, whereas in PowerShell `Get-Content` first *decoded* the file content into .NET strings, and, on sending the result to `mysql` via the pipeline, PowerShell *re-encoded* it based on `$OutputEncoding` (incorrectly, in Windows PowerShell).
- As an aside:

  - In v7.4+, PowerShell (Core) now pipes raw data *between external programs* and when using `>` to save an external program's output to a file - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375) for details, which also explains PowerShell's decoding and re-encoding behavior in more detail.

---

##### Background information:

Your problem isn't specific to the CLI you're using (`mysql`), it is rooted in a fundamental PowerShell behavior:

When PowerShell *sends* data to an *external (native) program* via the *pipeline*, it uses the character encoding stored in the [`$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding).

- Unfortunately, *Windows PowerShell* uses ASCII(!) encoding by default, meaning that non-ASCII characters (characters outside the 7-bit Unicode range, such as `é`) aren't supported and replaced with literal `?` characters, which is what you saw.

  - Therefore, you must (temporarily) assign a (BOM-less) UTF-8 encoding to `$OutputEncoding` before calling your command:

    ```bash
     # Instruct PowerShell to send UTF-8 to external programs via the pipeline.
     $OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()

     # ... now make your Get-Content ... | mysql call.
    ```
- [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *defaults* to *UTF-8*.

  - While this default is more sensible, it also introduces an awkward *asymmetry*: on *receiving* data from external programs does *not* default to UTF-8 on Windows<sup>[1]</sup> - see below.

When PowerShell *receives* data from external programs (via their stdout and stderr streams), PowerShell uses the encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to decode the data (into .NET strings).

- Unfortunately, *both* PowerShell editions defaults to the legacy *OEM code page* determined by the active legacy system locale (aka *language for non-Unicode programs*), e.g. [`437`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) on US-English systems.

  - [GitHub issue #7233](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7233) suggests making UTF-8 the *consistent* default in the future (which only PowerShell (Core) would benefit from, given that Windows PowerShell will only receive security-criticl fixes).
- While many CLIs honor this code page when producing their output, modern CLIs increasingly do not, given that such (fixed single-byte) code pages limit you to 256 characters. `node`, the Node.JS CLI, is a prominent example: it uses UTF-8 unconditionally. Others, such as `mysql`, allow you to request UTF-8 on demand.
- Thus, extra effort is needed<sup>[1]</sup> in order to properly decode UTF-8 *output* from external programs:

  ```bash
   # Instruct PowerShell to send UTF-8 to external programs via the pipeline
   # and to interpret their output as UTF-8.
   $OutputEncoding =
     [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Except if you've configured your system to use UTF-8 *system-wide*, but note that doing so has far-reaching consequences - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375).</sup>

Comment: Thanks, i understaind now why CMD work and not PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

Update, i find the solution !

in reality, PowerShell was at the root of the problem. I'm still not sure why, but this command line :

```
Get-Content $SQLfile -Encoding UTF8 | mysql --password=$($target.password) -h $($target.host) -P $($target.port) -u $($target.user) --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -f -D $db 2> $tempErrorFile
```

forces special characters to become "?".

all you had to do was take the 2nd command and add `" around the path of the .sql file, i.e. :

```
&cmd /c "mysql --password=$($target.password) -h $($target.host) -P $($target.port) -u $($target.user) --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -f -D $db < `"$SQLfile`" 2> $tempErrorFile"
```

If someone could explain to me why CMD works in this case but PowerShell does not.

Comment: Hey there! 
We're thrilled to hear that your question has been resolved. Remember, if you ever encounter any more questions or challenges while working with dbForge for MySQL, don't hesitate to contact our support team for a speedy resolution. You can reach us by emailing support@devart.com. Happy coding!