# How can I grep for a String in a powershell output using "|"?

Tags: windows, powershell, grep, select-string

It seems like in powershell,

```
echo ASDF | Select-String ASDF
```

outputs the obvious string, `ASDF`.

However, if i attempt to look at WinEvents, and look for an output, i.e.

```
Get-WinEvent -ListLog * | Select-String antrea
```

It seems as if the raw text is not scanned.

Whats the right way to use Select-STring as if it were a standard unix Grep ?

[image]

Comment: Get-WinEvent returns objects with properties, not strings.  You'll want to use Where-Object to filter the output -  `Get-WinEvent -ListLog * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object logname -match 'ssh'`

Comment: This is because `Get-WinEvent` returns an `object` not a `string` / `string[]`. To get all the `LogNames` related to `SSH` you can do  `Get-WinEvent -Listlog *ssh*`

Comment: In short: Unfortunately, [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) uses simple `.ToString()` stringification on its input objects rather than using the rich for-display representation produced by PowerShell's output-formatting system that you see when printing to the console. The workaround is to pipe to `Out-String -Stream` first; see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58732143/45375) to the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: Or you can force the output to string using Out-String `(Get-WinEvent -ListLog * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-String) -split "`r?`n" | Select-String ssh`

Comment: Good point, @Daniel, though using `Out-String -Stream` is simpler.

Comment: Since `Get-WinEvent` outputs `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord` objects and those objects don't have a `ToString()` override, you do not get the expected results. The object's wrapper provides its own `ToString()` method which simply outputs the object type when executed. You are effectively performing a string search against the string `System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord`.

Answer (score 2):

Pipelines in PowerShell are slightly different from UNIX style shells - instead of passing string output from one command to the next, PowerShell passes raw .NET object references.

So you'll want to inspect the *properties* of the objects returned by `Get-WinEvent` - here using the `Where-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-WinEvent -ListLog * |Where-Object LogName -Match SSH
```

---

If you want to inspect which properties are available on a specific object, use the `Get-Member` cmdlet:

```
PS ~> Get-WinEvent -ListLog * |Get-Member -MemberType Property

   TypeName: System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogConfiguration

Name                           MemberType Definition
----                           ---------- ----------
IsClassicLog                   Property   bool IsClassicLog {get;}
IsEnabled                      Property   bool IsEnabled {get;set;}
LogFilePath                    Property   string LogFilePath {get;set;}
LogIsolation                   Property   System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogIsolation LogIsolation {get;}
LogMode                        Property   System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogMode LogMode {get;set;}
LogName                        Property   string LogName {get;}
LogType                        Property   System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogType LogType {get;}
MaximumSizeInBytes             Property   long MaximumSizeInBytes {get;set;}
OwningProviderName             Property   string OwningProviderName {get;}
ProviderBufferSize             Property   System.Nullable[int] ProviderBufferSize {get;}
ProviderControlGuid            Property   System.Nullable[guid] ProviderControlGuid {get;}
ProviderKeywords               Property   System.Nullable[long] ProviderKeywords {get;set;}
ProviderLatency                Property   System.Nullable[int] ProviderLatency {get;}
ProviderLevel                  Property   System.Nullable[int] ProviderLevel {get;set;}
ProviderMaximumNumberOfBuffers Property   System.Nullable[int] ProviderMaximumNumberOfBuffers {get;}
ProviderMinimumNumberOfBuffers Property   System.Nullable[int] ProviderMinimumNumberOfBuffers {get;}
ProviderNames                  Property   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[string] ProviderNames {get;}
SecurityDescriptor             Property   string SecurityDescriptor {get;set;}
```

Comment: Hadn't noticed that you had already posted an answer when I closed this as a duplicate. My assumption was that the OP was looking for a quick-and-dirty search through the for-display output you get in the console, without having to specify or worry about specific property names.

Comment: Undoubtedly, querying properties is ultimately the best solution, but I've come to appreciate the quick-and-dirty approach in interactive use. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726#issuecomment-567628146 advocates for making `Select-String` default to using the formatting system's string representations (implied `Out-String -Stream`). In the meantime, I've rolled my own wrapper function with this functionality, available from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/46fea9e6e5ef1a3ceaf681c976cb68e3). It has become an indispensable tool for me.