# Using PowerShell sls (Select-String) vs grep vs findstr

Tags: string, powershell, console

Could someone clarify how sls (Select-String) works compared to grep and findstr?

grep: `grep <pattern> files.txt`

sls: `sls <pattern> files.txt`
(default parameter position for sls is pattern then file)

grep examples: `grep "search text" *.log`  ;  `cat *.log | grep "search text"`

sls examples: `sls "search text" *.log` ; `cat *.log | grep "search text"`

As an aside, all PowerShell Cmdlets are case-insensitive, unlike Linux tools which are generally always case-sensitive but also older tools like findstr which are case sensitive too, but findstr can be used in PowerShell, and works in situations where sls does not, for example: `Get-Service | findstr "Sec"` (this works without a problem!), but when we try to use sls in a similar way `Get-Service | sls "Sec"` we get nothing (presumably this fails because sls works with strings, but Get-Service returns an object, so that's understandable - but what is findstr doing then in that it can see the output as a string?).

So, my thinking is "ok, I need to make the output from Get-Service into a string to work with PowerShell Cmdlets", but that doesn't work (or not in a way that I would expect):

`Get-Service | Out-String | sls "Sec"` (gives results, but odd)

`(Get-Service).ToString() | sls "Sec"` (.ToString() just returns "System.Object[]")

How in general should I turn an object into a string so that it can manipulate the information (in the same way that `Get-Service | findstr "Sec"` can do so easily)?

Would appreciate if someone could clarify how things fit together in the above so that I can make more use of sls. In particular, `Get-Service | Out-String | sls "Sec"` does return stuff, just not the stuff I was expecting (is it searching for each character of "s" and "e" and "c" so is returning lots - that would not be very intuitive if so in my opinion)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use `Out-String` by default, it turns the piped input object (an array of service objects in this case) into a single string. Luckily, the `-Stream` switch allows each line to be output as a single string instead. Regarding case-sensitivity, `Select-String` supports the `-CaseSensitive` switch.

```
# For case-insensitive regex match
Get-Service | Out-String -Stream | Select-String "Sec"

# For case-sensitive regex match
Get-Service | Out-String -Stream | Select-String "Sec" -CaseSensitive

# For case-sensitive non-regex match
Get-Service | Out-String -Stream | Select-String "Sec" -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch
```

In either case, `Select-String` uses regex (use the `-SimpleMatch` switch to do a string match) to pattern match against each input string and outputs the entire string that matched the pattern. So if you only pipe into it a single string with many lines, then all lines will be returned on a successful match.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the clarification. That's cleared up something that I've not understood for a long time. Makes sense. I googled around and had not found this. I knew about the CaseSensitive switch, but not the SimpleMatch, that's also very useful. Will be very easy to use Select-String in future with this information.

Comment: One thing that I'm left still curious on though: what happens in the findstr case then? When we pipe to a non-Cmdlet, does PowerShell say "ah, this findstr thing is not a Cmdlet, so do an `Out-String -Stream` before passing it" because it appears that it is giving findstr each line as a single string, right?

Comment: +1 for the answer, but the `findstr` explanation in the comment is confusing. In fact, PowerShell _implicitly_ implies `Out-String -Stream` when piping to external programs, something it should always have done for non-string input to `Select-Object` as well (see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726). That is, it is PowerShell that feeds individual lines of the effectively `Out-String -Stream`-stringified input to `findstr`, and it is PowerShell that invariably terminates each stringified input (line) with a newline. /cc @YorSubs.

Answer (score 4):

To complement [AdminOfThings' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59230138/45375):

- In order **to find strings among the lines of the *for-display* string representations of *non-string* input objects** *as they would print to the console* you indeed have to **pipe to `Out-String -Stream`**, whereas **by default, simple `.ToString()` stringification is applied**<sup>[1]</sup>.

  - **You shouldn't have to do this *manually*, however**: `Select-String` should do it *implicitly*, as suggested in [GitHub issue #10726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726).
- Curiously, **when piping to *external* programs such as `findstr.exe`, PowerShell already *does* apply `Out-String -Stream` implicitly**; e.g:

  - `Get-Date 1/1/2019 | findstr January` works (in `en`-based cultures), because it is implicitly the same as 
    `Get-Date 1/1/2019 | Out-String -Stream | findstr January`
  - By contrast, `Get-Date 1/1/2019 | Select-String January` is the equivalent of  
    `(Get-Date 1/1/2019).ToString([cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture) | Select-String January`, and therefore does *not* work, because the input evaluates to `01/01/2019 00:00:00`.

---

<sup>[1] More accurately, `.psobject.ToString()` is called, either as-is, or - if the object's `ToString` method supports an `IFormatProvider`-typed argument - as `.psobject.ToString([cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)` so as to obtain a *culture-invariant* representation - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375) for more information.</sup>

Comment: Indeed, seemed curious to me above that this happened implicitly when passed to findstr but not for Select-String (I see no reason not to). Often there are deeper technical reasons for the why (which I usually don't understand frankly) but it looks like it would have been better behaviour if `Select-String` implicitly did `Out-String -Stream` in the same way as when piping to `findstr`. I've always found Select-String awkward to use in the past in this way (so I just avoided it) and never understood why. Thanks for the explanation (and hopefully the proposed change is implemented).