# Distinguish different kinds of hashtables in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

It looks like there are different kinds of hashtables in PowerShell, ones that are case sensitive and ones that are not. When defining a hashtable as the following **it's not case sensitive**:

```
$ht = @{ "Test" = "HI" }

$ht.Contains("test") #returns true, even with key name lowercase
True

$ht.ContainsKey("test") #returns true, even with key name lowercase
True

$ht.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

However, if you define it as such **it is case sensitive**:

```
$ht_caseSensitive = New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable
$ht_caseSensitive.Add("Test", "HI")

$ht_caseSensitive.Contains("test") # returns false, since it's all lowercase
False

$ht_caseSensitive.ContainsKey("test") # returns false, same with contains key function
False

$ht_caseSensitive.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

However, as shown in the `GetType()` output, I can't seem to find a way to differentiate between these objects.

- Why is one case sensitive and the other is not?
- Is there any way I
  can differentiate between them when it's important to know whether
  I'm dealing with a hashtable that's case sensitive or not?

Comment: By default PS hashtables are case insensitive. ONLY by defining the object as in your 2nd example or a couple of very rare methods e.g. export/importing xml can they be made case sensitive.

Comment: This is also a PSScriptAnalyzer rule: [UseLiteralInitializerForHashtable](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/UseLiteralInitializerForHashtable.md)

Answer (score 5):

> Why is one case sensitive and the other is not?

Because **PowerShell often intentionally modifies default .NET functionality to be case-*insensitive*, in keeping with PowerShell being case-insensitive *overall***.

- Therefore, while **hashtable *literal*** `@{ "Test" = "HI" }` indeed creates a `[hashtable]` ([`System.Collections.Hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable)) instance, *PowerShell constructs it with an explicitly case-INSENSITIVE equality comparer* behind the scenes.<sup>[1]</sup>
- By contrast, ***constructing* a `[hashtable]` instance** directly honors *.NET's defaults*, which is to simply call the `.Equals()` method for key lookups, which in the case of *string* keys (the typical case) amounts to *ordinal, case-SENSITIVE* comparison.

---

> Is there any way I can differentiate between them when it's important to know whether I'm dealing with a hashtable that's case sensitive or not?

**If you always use PowerShell hashtable *literals* and / or construct (initialize) hashtables *via* literal `@{}`, you'll always get case-*insensitive* lookups.**

---

In case you still need to reflect on a given `[hashtable]` instance to determine whether its equality comparer is case-sensitive or not, you can use the following - obscure - technique:

```
# Create a case-SENSITIVE hashtable.
# Note: in PowerShell v5+, the more efficient alternative is: 
#       $someHashTable = [hashtable]::new()
$someHashTable = New-Object hashtable # System.Collections.Hashtable

# Use reflection to get the *non-public* (protected, in this case)
# .EqualityComparer property value.
$equalityComparer = [hashtable].GetProperty(
   'EqualityComparer',
   [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'NonPublic, Instance'
 ).GetValue($someHashTable)

# The hashtable is case-sensitive if it either doesn't define
# an explicit comparer or uses one that is case-sensitive.
$isCaseSensitive = $null -eq $equalityComparer -or 
                   0 -ne $equalityComparer.Compare('a', 'A')
```

---

<sup>[1] In *Windows PowerShell* (versions up to v5.1), this comparer was - surprisingly - *culture-sensitive*; in PowerShell [Core] as of v7.0, it uses *ordinal* (but still case-insensitive) comparison. Note that in many other contexts PowerShell uses *culture-invariant* behavior instead - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).</sup>