# Check whether a dictionary is case sensitive

Tags: powershell, dictionary, case-sensitive

I would like to check whether a given dictionary (`$Dictionary -is [System.Collections.IDictionary]`) is case sensitive?

- For a `[HashTable]`, it is described here:
  [Distinguish different kinds of hashtables in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60592703/1701026)
- For a `$Dictionary = [system.collections.generic.dictionary[string,object]]::new()`, I might simply do: `$Dictionary.Comparer.Equals('A', 'a')`
- But for e.g. an `[Ordered]` dictionary, I have no clue...

Is there a generic way to check the `EqualityComparer` of an dictionary?
Or: how do I cover all dictionary flavors?

Comment: Not a great idea to rely on reflection to know if it is case-sensitive or not. I assume if you need to know if it is case-sensitive or not you don't have control of its instantiation and by assuming that we can also assume that the dictionary is pre-populated so what you could do is get a dictionary Key and check if you can get the pair value with a `.ToUpper()` and `.ToLower()`. Since hashtables and ordered dicitionary keys are of type object it makes sense their default comparer is not `public`.

Comment: What if the comparer is custom and only considers `A = a` but not `B = b` - would you consider it case-insensitive or not? :)

Comment: Here's an example of a [comparer that's both case-insensitive and case-sensitive](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/1202a26269442a0e96bee9138191cf89) - what should your desired mechanism say here?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I see your point. Maybe I should change the question: is there a common way to retrieve the comparer from a dictionary sothat I can reuse that on another dictionary?

Comment: The ordered dict doesn't have a private or internal property for its comparer, you can get it from the field directly: `($dict = [ordered]@{}).GetType().GetField('_comparer', [System.Reflection.BindingFlags] 'Instance, NonPublic').GetValue($dict)` still would advise against this.

Comment: Answer to your question "Is generic way to check the `EqualityComparer` of an dictionary?" is no, there isn't you can do your best to keep track of how to handle each specific case, some might be via reflection like hashtable or ordered dictionary some might be via a public property like generic dictionary but that covers only specific cases, I believe there is no way to cover all types implementing the `IDictionary`. The reflection approaches are obviously not recommended, nobody is ensuring you that those private fields or properties will change in the future.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, thank you for your example and comments. For your background: I am currently building a toolset for Object Graphs (see: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20591) which would include cmdlets like `Merge-ObjectGraph`, `Sort-ObjectGraph` and  `Compare-ObjectGraph` (which I recall that you even suggested) for this I am building a "interface" class to iterate through the object nodes and for that i would like the "node interface" act the same as the actual contained object/properties. I will share this with you when I have something available.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, **no** is also answer, so don't hesitate to formalize it and I will accept it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, and answering your question:

> Is there a generic way to check the `EqualityComparer` of an dictionary?

As far as I can tell, **there is not**, you can do your best to keep track of how to handle each specific case, some might be via reflection like with [`Hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=net-8.0) or [`OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=net-8.0) and some might be via a public property like with [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-8.0) and other generic types **but that covers only specific cases**.

I believe there is no way to cover all types implementing the [`IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary?view=net-8.0) and [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2?view=net-8.0) interfaces. The reflection approaches are obviously not recommended, **nobody is ensuring you that those private fields or properties will change in the future**.

Leaving that aside, below might help you get a better perspective on how you can approach this problem.

```
$supportedGenericTypes = @(
    # there is no interface ensuring that a type implementing `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`
    # will have a `.Comparer` property, you will need to manually check if they actually do
    # before adding them to this list
    [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2]
    [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2]
    [System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2]
)

[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string, string]]::new(),
[ordered]@{},
@{},
[System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary[string, string]]::new(),
[System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary[string, string]]::new() |
    ForEach-Object {
        $type = $_.GetType()
        if ($type.IsGenericType -and $type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() -in $supportedGenericTypes) {
            $comparer = $_.Comparer
            # need to cover any custom type implementing `IDicitonary<TKey, TValue>` here...
        }
        elseif (-not $type.IsGenericType) {
            $instance = $_

            switch ($type) {
                ([System.Collections.Hashtable]) {
                    $comparer = [System.Collections.Hashtable].
                        GetField('_keycomparer', [System.Reflection.BindingFlags] 'NonPublic,Instance').
                        GetValue($instance)
                }
                ([System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]) {
                    $comparer = [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary].
                        GetField('_comparer', [System.Reflection.BindingFlags] 'NonPublic,Instance').
                        GetValue($instance)
                }
                # need to cover any custom type implementing `IDicitonary` here...
            }
        }
        else {
            throw [System.NotImplementedException]::new()
        }

        [pscustomobject]@{
            Type     = $type
            Comparer = $comparer
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, as said, **Don't** ("*Not a great idea*") is also an answer and as @MathiasR.Jessen suggested: the comparer is not just about *case* sensitivity. So I decided to let this idea go and rely on the actual dictionary comparer while recursively iterating through the Object Graphs for the toolset I am currently building, see: https://github.com/iRon7/ObjectGraphTools