# Can you use format specifiers directly in PowerShell expanding string?

Tags: powershell, string-formatting

In PowerShell, I can use Expanding strings to insert variable values into strings ([Answer with more details about that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998)):

```
PS C:\> $UtcNow = [DateTime]::UtcNow
PS C:\> "UtcNow = $UtcNow"
UtcNow = 08/10/2020 09:31:51
```

I can do it less conveniently using `String.Format` or the `-f` operator, and then I can provide format specifiers:

```
PS C:\> "UtcNow = {0:u}" -f $UtcNow
UtcNow = 2020-08-10 09:31:51Z

PS C:\> [string]::Format("UtcNow = {0:u}", $UtcNow)
UtcNow = 2020-08-10 09:31:51Z
```

## Question: Is there a way to use a format specifier in and expanding string?

## What I've tried

```
PS C:\> "UtcNow = $UtcNow:u"   # Doesn't work
UtcNow = 

PS C:\> "UtcNow = ${UtcNow:u}"   # Doesn't work
UtcNow = 

PS C:\> "UtcNow = $($UtcNow.ToString("u"))"  # Works, but is quite cumbersome
UtcNow = 2020-08-10 09:31:51Z
```

Comment: You can probably just change your culture settings of the session if you want it in the same format for the whole session. Then you dont need to bother about the format later on in your script.

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-culture-information-in-powershell-to-format-dates/

Comment: @DanielBjörk: Interesting... But doesn't work, since PowerShell always uses Invariant culture for expanding string - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732) linked from the answer in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No, expandable strings in PowerShell don't evaluate format specifiers

`-f` is the way to go :)