# powershell: stuck with easy DateTime script

Tags: powershell

Currently having a really really hard time with something that looks very easy to fix but for some reason just doesnt work.
I have an Excel file with a column called "Date" with uh...dates in it with the following format; 21-3-2021. All I want is to use these dates to set an AD account Expiration date.

So this is what I did:

```
import-CSV ".\Example.csv" | % {

$User = $._username
$ExpirationDate = [datetime]::Parse($_.Date).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')

if ($_.Date -ne '') {
Set-ADAccountExpiration $User $ExpirationDate
}
else {
Clear-ADAccountExpiration $user
}
```

*Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."*

Please, if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong I would be really happy.
This is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **single-argument [`[datetime]::Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.Parse) overload** - e.g.,
`[datetime]::Parse('21-3-2021')` - **implicitly uses the date/time formats of the *current* culture**<sup>[1]</sup>, as reflected in `$PSCulture` and [`Get-Culture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Culture), and it seems that that current culture in effect for you doesn't recognize a date string such as `'21-3-2021'`.

A simple solution is to **explicitly specify a culture in which such a date format is valid** and pass that culture as the second argument:

```
# The German culture supports such a format.
# Sample output is from my en-US (US English system).
PS> [datetime]::Parse('21-3-2021', [cultureinfo] 'de-DE')

Sunday, March 21, 2021 12:00:00 AM
```

---

**If you had a truly exotic format** not recognized by any of the predefined cultures (which *isn't* the case here), you could **use the [`[datetime]::ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ParseExact) method**:

```
PS> [datetime]::ParseExact('21-3-2021', 'd\-M\-yyyy', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)

Sunday, March 21, 2021 12:00:00 AM
```

Note:

- The `-` instances are `\`-escaped to ensure that they are matched *verbatim* in the input; by default, they are treated as *abstract placeholders* for any of the date-component separators supported by the target culture.
- The specific culture context passed as the 3rd argument - the  [*invariant culture*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) here - would only matter if the input string contained abstract placeholders and/or culture-specific month *names*, such as "März" for March; you can pass `$null` to use the *current* culture.

---

<sup>[1] Note that **if you *cast* a string to a type in PowerShell** - e.g., `[datetime] '1/13'` - **the [*invariant culture*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) is *always* used** for parsing; in other words: `[datetime] '1/13'` is equivalent to:

`[datetime]::Parse('1/13', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)`.

The invariant culture is derived from the US-English culture and is designed to be both independent of the current culture and to be stable over time, which makes it suitable for *programmatic* use - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375) for more.</sup>