# Can't seem to use generic collection with a PowerShell class

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to invoke the [`List[T](IEnumerable)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__) directly adding an item to the initial `List` like so, where `T` is a PowerShell class I've written (the below example uses the class name `Thing`:

```bsh
$someObject = Get-Thing # returns a single object
$list = [List[Thing]]::new(@( $someObject ))
```

However, this yields an error suggesting it can't find the overload for this constructor:

> Cannot find an overload for "List`1" and the argument count: "1".

Setting `List[T]` to the `Object` class works, however:

```bsh
$someObject = Get-Thing
$list = [List[Object]]::new(@( $someObject ))
```

While this works, I'm unsure why I'm unable to use my PowerShell class as the type. My understanding is that [only context-bound types and (by default) nested types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/#advantages-and-disadvantages-of-generics) are unable to be used with generics, but the following shows that my class is not a `ContextBoundObject`:

```bsh
class Thing {
  $Name

  Thing($name) {
    $this.Name = $name
  }
}
$thing = [Thing]::new('Bender')
$thing -is [System.ContextBoundObject] # ==> False
```

I'm not certain if a PowerShell class would be a nested type of some sort, and [about_Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7) does not mention nested types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm unsure why I'm unable to use my PowerShell class as the type

The array subexpression operator `@()` returns its results as `[object[]]` - a type which satisfies the argument type `[IEnumerable[object]]` - which is why it always works when you use `[object]` as the type parameter for the receiving collection type.

---

So, what to do about that?

If the array consists only of `[Thing]`'s, you can explicitly cast to a more specific collection type that implements `[IEnumerable[Thing]]`:

```
$list = [List[Thing]]::new([Thing[]]@( $someObject ))
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63981775/45375), which explains the problem well and offers an effective solution:

**PowerShell's *casts*** are not only **syntactically more convenient** than constructor calls, but also **more flexible** when it comes to *on-demand type conversions*.

Indeed, **using a *cast* instead of calling a *constructor*, via the static `::new()` method, does work**:

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

class Thing { [string] $Name; Thing([string] $name) { $this.Name = $name } }

# Both of the following work:

# Single [Thing] instance.
$list = [List[Thing]] [Thing]::new('one')

# Multiple [Thing] instances, as an array, via the grouping operator, (...)
# @(...), the array subexpression operator, works too, but is unnecessary.
$list = [List[Thing]] ([Thing]::new('one'), [Thing]::new('two'))
```

---

#### PowerShell's automatic type conversions, as also used in casts:

Unfortunately, as of this writing the rules aren't documented, but [a comment in the source-code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/8f7d308eaaf3d3ad1efdc778663a25b7b1671aa2/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/LanguagePrimitives.cs#L1627) provides a high-level overview, as does the (pretty low-level) [*ETS type converters*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/ets/typeconverters) documentation, which can be summarized as follows, in descending order of precedence:

- First, **engine-internal, fixed conversion rules** may be applied (see source-code link above).

  - A notable internal rule concerns ***to-string* conversions**: while *any* .NET type supports it by an *explicit* call to its `.ToString()` method (inherited from the root of the object hierarchy, `System.Object`), PowerShell applies custom rules:

    - If a type has a culture-sensitive `.ToString(<IFormatProvider>)` overload, **PowerShell passes the *invariant* culture deliberately, to achieve a *culture-invariant* representation**, whereas a direct `.ToString()` call would yield a culture-*sensitive* representation - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375) for details; e.g., in a culture where `,` is the decimal mark, `[string] 1.2` returns `'1.2'` (period), whereas `(1.2).ToString()` returns `'1,2'` (comma).
    - **Collections**, including arrays, are **stringified by concatenating their (stringified) elements with a space as the separator** (by default, can be overridden with preference variable `$OFS`); e.g., `[string] (1, 2)` returns `1 2`, whereas `(1, 2).ToString()` returns merely `System.Object[]`.
  - Also, PowerShell **converts freely**:

    - **between different *number types*** (when possible).
    - **between numbers and strings** (in a culture-*invariant* manner, recognizing only `.` as the decimal mark when converting from a string).
    - and **allows any data type to be converted to (interpreted as) as *Boolean*** - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375) for the rules.
    - **from a *scalar* to an *array* / list type** (e.g., `[int[]] 42` creates a single-element array, and `[System.Collections.Generic.List[int]] 42` creates a single-element list; small *caveat*: there are *bugs* with certain list types - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76908998/45375)).
- Next, **[`TypeConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter) or ([`PSTypeConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSTypeConverter)) classes** that implement custom conversions for specific types are considered.
- If the **input type is a *string* (`[string]`), a static `::Parse()` method is considered**, if present: first, one with a culture-sensitive signature, `::Parse(<string>, <IFormatProvider>)`, in which case the *invariant* culture is passed, and, otherwise one with signature `::Parse(<string>)`.
- Next, a **single-argument *constructor*** is considered, if the input type matches the argument's type or is convertible to it.
- If an **implicit or explicit [conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)** exists for conversion between the input and the target type.
- Finally, if the input object implements the **[`System.IConvertible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IConvertible) interface** and the target type is a supported-by-the-implementation [primitive .NET type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive#System_Type_IsPrimitive) except `[IntPtr]` and `[UIntPtr]` or one of the following types: `[datetime]`, `[DBNull]`, `[decimal]`.