# PowerShell classes with single-argument constructors do not validate data type

Tags: powershell

I'm designing a module and using classes to type-validate my parameters. I noticed that, when attempting to type-validate input parameters, a class with a single-argument constructor appears to act as a type accelerator instead of validating data type.

Example:

```
Class stack {
  $a
  $b
  stack($inp) {
    $this.a = $inp
    $this.b = 'anything'
  }
}

function foo {
  Param(
    [stack]$bar
  )
  $bar
}

PS>foo -bar 'hello'
a      b
-      -
hello  anything
```

$bar has been type accelerated into an instantiation of stack.

Compare this to the same class with a constructor that takes 2 arguments:

```
Class stack {
  $a
  $b
  stack($inp,$inp2) {
    $this.a = $inp
    $this.b = 'anything'
  }
}

function foo {
  Param(
    [stack]$bar
  )
  $bar
}

PS>foo -bar 'hello'
foo : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'bar'. Cannot convert the "hello" value of type "System.String" to type "stack".
```

Now the class type is correctly validating the input parameter.

I first saw this in PS5.1  on Windows 10, but I just tried it on my private laptop with pwsh 7.2.1 and seems to be the same.

Is there a workaround to this behavior? Is it a bug?

Edit: Well, after further testing, I realized this also happens if I supply 2 input parameters for the constructor with 2 arguments, e.g., `foo -bar 'hello' 'world'`. So I guess it's probably intended, and I'm doing something wrong. Can I use classes to validate my data types for input parameters? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is unrelated to [type accelerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Accelerators), which are simply *short alias names* for .NET type names; e.g., `[regex]` is short for `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]`.

Instead, **you're seeing PowerShell's flexible *automatic type conversions***, which include translating *casts* (e.g. `[stack] ...`) and *type constraints* (ditto, in the context of an assignment or inside a `param(...)` block) into *constructor calls* or `::Parse()` calls, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63982452/45375).

- Therefore, given that your `[stack]` class has a (non-type-constrained) *single-argument* constructor, something like `[stack] 'hello'` is automatically translated into `[stack]::new('hello')`, i.e. a constructor call - and that is also what happens when you pass *argument* `'hello'` to a *parameter* whose type is `[stack]`.

**I suggest *not* fighting these automatic conversions**, as they are usually helpful.

**In the rare event that you do need to ensure that the type of the argument passed is *exactly* of the type specified in the parameter declaration (or of a *derived* type)**,  you can use the following technique (using type `[datetime]` as an example, whose full .NET type name is `System.DateTime`):

```
function Foo {

  param(
    # Ensure that whatever argument is passed is already of type [datetime]
    [PSTypeName('System.DateTime')]
    $Bar
  )
  
  "[$Bar]"
}
```

<sup>Kudos to you for discovering the `[PSTypeName()]` attribute for this use case.</sup>

- *Without* the `[PSTypeName(...)]` attribute, a call such as `Foo 1/1/1970` would work, because the *string* `'1/1/1970'` is automatically converted to `[datetime]` by PowerShell.
- *With* the **[`[PSTypeName(...)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSTypeNameAttribute)  attribute**, only an actual `[datetime]` argument is accepted (or, for types that can be sub-classed, an instance of a type *derived* from the specified type).

  - **Important**: **Specify the target type's *full* .NET type name** (e.g. `'System.DateTime'` rather than just `'datetime'`) to target it unambiguously.

    - However, for *PowerShell custom `class`es*, their name *is* the full name (they are not inside a *namespace*), so in the case of your `[stack]` class, the attribute would be `[PSTypeName('stack')]`
  - ***Any* type name is accepted**, even if it doesn't refer to an existing .NET type or custom `class`, and **any such non-existent type would require an argument to use a matching *virtual* [*ETS* (PowerShell's Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) type name**. In fact, **supporting such virtual type names is the *primary purpose* of this attribute**.<sup>[1]</sup> E.g., if `[PSTypeName('Bar')]` were used, you could pass a *custom object* with an *ETS* type name of `Bar` as follows:
    `[pscustomobject] @{ PSTypeName = 'Bar'; Baz = 'quux' }`

---

<sup>[1] To quote from the linked docs (emphasis added): "This attribute is used to restrict the type name of the parameter, *when the type goes beyond the .NET type system*."</sup>

Comment: I see. Thanks for the thorough explanation. It seems I misunderstood the typing constraint on a parameter as a means of data validation. I am actually seeking something like an enum but for objects instead of a set of strictly constrained strings. Is this validateScript approach for classes the optimal way to go about this?

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Blaisem. The `ValidateScript` approach isn't great, especially in Windows PowerShell, where you cannot provide  a _friendly error message_, but if you truly want to avoid _automatic type conversions_, then you either need to use this attribute or use an _unconstrained_ (or `[object]`-typed) parameter and perform custom validation in the function/script _body_. But the question is: why aren't the automatic type conversions acceptable, if they result in an instance of the expected type?

Comment: I've written the code to instantiate a class object in a variable, so I can dynamically reuse this variable in various places -- as function inputs, control flow conditions, reference hashtable keys via a property, etc.. Eventually, I have to deliver this module, so my goal is understandable code: communicating types concisely, robustly validating for easier debugging, and avoiding boilerplate. Reusing non-mutating variables for prominent objects within a specific context seemed to me like a way to establish a comfortable reference point to help the reader track what's going on in that context

Comment: But I'm new at this scale of PowerShell, so I may be going about it wrong. If I have to reconstruct the class for every function, I'm not sure if that's better than what I am doing. It's a new concept to me, so I'm not sure what to make of it yet, but maybe it's just as good or better.

Comment: @Blaisem, there's a lot of "automagic" going on in PowerShell, for better or worse. I suggest embracing it rather than fighting it. Do _not_ think of PowerShell as C# with different syntax - it isn't, and that mindset will be a perennial pain point.

Comment: thanks for the more in-depth info. To come back to the point: I believe I seem to have found a way to do this kind of validation by casting it via `[PSTypeName('<class name>')]`. Whether it's the most elegant way to code instead of using the auto conversion is something I'll have to think about, but PowerShell's versatility still catches me off guard.

Comment: @Blaisem, that attribute is an excellent find and indeed does what you want in a more direct way than the `[ValidateScript()]` approach - I've updated the answer accordingly. That said, the fact that this attribute is little-known and little-used is an indication that the kind of validation you're looking for is usually _not_ sought, and that instead the "automagic" type conversions are usually embraced and accepted.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to validate the passed type you need to actually validate, not just cast the input as a specific type.

```
function foo {
Param(
    [ValidateScript({$_ -is [stack]})]
    $bar
)
    $bar
}
```

Doing this will not try to cast the input as a specific type, and will fail if the input type is wrong.

Comment: I totally missed the point lols, thanks for letting me know

Comment: Good points, but as @Blaisem themselves discovered, `[PSTypeName('stack')]` is a more direct expression of this intent.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'foo' function requires a [stack] argument, it doesn't create one.

So your call should be as follow:

```
foo -bar ([stack]::new('fun:foo','hello'))
```

I don't know exactly how you will use it but if the goal is to validate arguments, I would suggest to specify the types everywhere... here is a small example but it can be improved, just an example:

```
Class stack {
    [string]$a
    [string]$b
    stack([string]$inp,[string]$inp2) {
        $this.a = $inp
        $this.b = $inp2
    }
}

function foo {
    Param([stack]$bar)
    $bar
}


function foo2 {
  Param([array]$bar)
  [stack]::new($bar[0],$bar[1])
}


foo -bar ([stack]::new('fun:foo','hello'))
foo2 -bar 'fun:foo2','hello'
foo2 -bar @('fun:foo2','hello2')
```

Comment: I am typing everything. Just left that part out for the example. What did you mean by fun:foo?

Comment: 'fun:foo' is just a string I choose for the example (function:foo and function:foo2), didn't though it will be confusing

Answer (score 1):

Aha, I thought I had seen something to this effect somewhere. I luckily managed to get it working by applying the description from an [article](https://www.powershellstation.com/2016/05/22/custom-objects-and-pstypename/) on using the PSTypeName in PSCustomObjects for type-validation to classes. It turns out that classes also work with the same syntax.

In summary, it seems one has to type [PSTypeName('stack')] to use class types to validate data types.

```
Class stack {
  $a
  $b
  stack($inp) {
    $this.a = $inp
    $this.b = 'anything'
  }
}

function foo {
  Param(
    [PSTypeName('stack')]$bar
  )
  $bar
}
PS>foo -bar 'hello'
foo : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'bar', because PSTypeNames of the argument do not match the PSTypeName required by the parameter: stack.

PS>$test = [stack]::new('Overflow')
PS>foo -bar $test
a        b
-        -
Overflow anything
```

Comment: Again, kudos for discovering this use for the [`[PSTypeName(...)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSTypeNameAttribute) attribute, but not that its intended use is _not_ to constrain parameters to true .NET types (including custom `class` instances) and thereby _suppress automatic type conversions_. Instead, its purpose is to support _virtual types_ provided via PowerShell's ETS (Extended Type System); emphasis added: "This attribute is used to restrict the type name of the parameter, _when the type goes beyond the .NET type system_."