# PowerShell conversion of String into FileInfo automatically - What is this called?

Tags: c#, powershell, types, type-conversion, powershell-7.0

Some sample code to illustrate what I'm talking about. I've got a utility class with a single method. That method takes one argument: a System.IO.FileInfo object. From the PowerShell side I can pass in a System.String object and everything "just works". I'm curious as a develop getting more into PowerShell this year I'm curious:

1. What feature of PowerShell allows this to happen?
2. Is this open to extension / use by any developer in PowerShell 7.x? (non-internal)

C#:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestProject
{
    public class Utility
    {
        public string GetFirstLine(FileInfo fileInfo)
        {
            string firstLine = File.ReadLines(fileInfo.FullName).First();
            return firstLine;
        }
    }
}
```

PowerShell:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\assemblies\TestProject.dll"
$util = [TestProject.Utility]::New()
$util.GetFirstLine("C:\temp\random-log.txt")
```

Note: I realize this is trivial example. Code is meant for quickly illustrating the capability in PowerShell I am interested in.

Comment: PowerShell casts automatically if possible; it is as if you wrote `$util.GetFirstLine(([IO.FileInfo] "C:\temp\random-log.txt"))`.

Comment: By feature you mean the ability of type conversion whenever possible?

Comment: It's just implicit conversion - PowerShell tries to resolve the correct method signature, fails to find an exact match, and then attempts to convert the string value to the target type. If a type converter or type adapter is registered for the target type, it's used, otherwise PowerShell resolves a constructor for the target type that takes 1 argument of the source type, and uses the result of instantiating such an object (eg. `GetFirstLine("C:\temp\random-log.txt")` is evaluated as `GetFirstLine([System.IO.FileInfo]::new("C:\temp\random-log.txt"))` at runtime)

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen that was the level I was needed. Led me to the right type of language to locate the following. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/ets/typeconverters?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You should post your explanation as an answer.

Comment: @BuddyJoe I'm on my phone rn, I'll post an answer as soon as I get back to a full keyboard :)

Comment: Good to know that there's official documentation, @BuddyJoe - though the linked topic is quite technical. A perhaps more easily digestible summary of PowerShell's automatic type conversions / casts can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63982452/45375).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although PowerShell is more or less a "real .NET language", it does *extend* the common type system with an array of behaviors that sometimes conflict with what you know about .NET's type system behavior from languages like C# or VB.NET.

This additional type system layer bolted on top of the CLR is aptly named the **Extended Type System** (ETS), and it's directly responsible for making argument conversion "just work" the way you've observed.

---

When the PowerShell runtime reaches a method invocation statement like `$util.GetFirstLine("C:\temp\random-log.txt")`, it has to pick an appropriate overload, just like the C# compiler does.

The first step is to identity overloads for which the number of arguments passed can cover all mandatory parameters of the given overload signature. In your case, only 1 such signature can be resolved at this step, so PowerShell now has two pieces of the puzzle:

- A method stub with the signature `string GetFirstLine(FileInfo fileInfo)`
- An argument value of type `[string]`

At this point, the C# compiler would give up and report [CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.FileInfo'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1503).

PowerShell, on the other hand, is designed to be *helpful* in the hands of system administrators and operators - people who might not put too much thought into data structure design, but who are chiefly concerned with *string representations* of data (after all, this is what `bash`, `cmd`, etc. taught them to use).

To meaningfully convert from a string (or any other non-compliant argument type) at just the right time, ETS comes with [a number of facilities and hooks for implicit type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/ets/typeconverters?view=powershell-7.2) that the runtime then attempts, one by one, until it either finds a valid conversion mechanism, or fails (at which point the method invocation fails too):

- Built-in converters

  - These take priority to handle the most common edge cases, like `null`-conversions, "truthy/falsy"-to-real-`[bool]` conversions, stringification of scalars, etc. - without these, PowerShell would be a pain in the ass to work with interactively.
  - Example:

    - These flow control statements behave exactly like you'd expect thanks to built-in conversions: `if($null){ <# unreachable #> }`, `do{ Stop-Process chrome }while(Get-Process chome)`
- Custom type converters

  - These are concrete type converter implementations registered to one or more target types - this can be useful for modifying the binding behavior of complex types you've brought with you into the runtime.
  - Example:

    - The RSAT ActiveDirectory module uses type adapters to interchange between the different data types modeling specific directory object classes - allowing you to seamlessly pipe output from `Get-ADComputer` (very specific output type) to `Get-ADObject` (generalized output type) and vice versa.
- Parse converters

  - If no appropriate built-in or custom type converter can be found, PowerShell will attempt to resolve a `Parse()` method with the appropriate return type on the target type.
  - Example:

    - The cast operation `[timespan]'1.02:15:25'` can succeed this way.
- Constructor-based conversions

  - If none of the above works, PowerShell will attempt to resolve a constructor that can be invoked with a single parameter argument of the source type given.
  - **This is what happens in your case** - PowerShell effectively excutes `$util.GetFirstLine([System.IO.FileInfo]::new("C:\temp\random-log.txt"))` for you
- CTS conversions

  - Finally, if all of ETS' conversation attempts fail, it falls back to resolving implicit (and eventually explicit) conversions defined by the types themselves.
  - Example:

    - This conversion succeeds because the `[DateTimeOffset]` type has an implicit conversion operator for `[DateTime]`: `(Get-Date) -as [DateTimeOffset]`

---

The concrete type converters mentioned above will automatically be respected by ETS if they've either been included in a type data file (see [`about_Types.ps1xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml)), or if the target type is public and the source definition was decorated with a `[TypeConverter()]` attribute.

Additionally, you can register new type conversion primitives at runtime with the `Update-TypeData` cmdlet.

Of course the madness doesn't stop there, there are also additional facilities specifically for converting/transform *command* arguments, but that's beyond the scope of this question :)