# convert varying timestamps to a uniform format

Tags: powershell, datetime

I am trying to convert a timestamp to milliseconds in a script using an external program. The external program outputs the time in the shortest possible format
Example the external program can output any of the following formats:

```
"1:33.823" #1min:33 seconds.823 - shortest
"11:33.823" #11min:33 seconds.823 - short
"1:11:33.823" #1 hour 11min:33 seconds.823 - long
```

I need this value converted in milliseconds. so I tried `[timestamp] $mystring` but it complains about the format in the first case. I thought about parsing the format manually with something like

```
$format='h\:mm\:ss\.ff'
[timespan]::ParseExact($mystring,$format , $null)
```

But the problem with this approach is that I have to predict every possible output format of the external program and implement all the cases manually (if shortest then `$format=m\:ss\.fff else if short then $format=...`

Or I can possibly split and define the string, loop from the back and define the attributes of the TimeSpan object manually.

My question is: are there any standard (good practice) conversion methods for my case provided in the language or are my "quick and dirty" solutions common?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like the "external program" is reporting elapsed time and not a timestamp. I think you want to use `[timespan]::Parse($mystring) `.

Comment: @JonathanDodds, yes it is elapsed time actually, `$t="1:33.823";[timespan]::Parse($t)` won't work, thus the question

Comment: TimeSpan can accept an array : $formats = @("m:s.fff", "h:m:s.fff")  Then use [timespan]::ParseExact($mystring,$formats , $null) but doesn't work.  You need to use DateTime instead : [DateTime]::ParseExact($mystring,$formats , $null).TimeOfDay  I debugged in c#.  Have seen case in the past like this where timespan doesn't work but DateTime does.  You always can use timeofday to convert DateTime to TimeSpan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ensure that your time-span strings have at least *3* `:`-separated components, you can cast them directly to [`[timespan]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeSpan) (which, behind the scenes, delegates to `[timespan]::Parse($inputString, [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)`)<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
@(
  "1:33.823" #1min:33 seconds.823 - shortest
  "11:33.823" #11min:33 seconds.823 - short
  "1:11:33.823" #1 hour 11min:33 seconds.823 - long
) | ForEach-Object {
  $colonCount = ($_ -replace '[^:]').Length
  [timespan] ('0:' * [math]::Max(0, (3 - $colonCount - 1)) + $_)
}
```

The above transforms the input strings to `0:1:33.823`, `0:11:33.823`, and `1:11:33.823` before casting, i.e. prepends `0:` components as needed.

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell by design uses the *invariant culture* when possible - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63982452/45375) for more information.</sup>

Comment: this is indeed quite elegant, the idea I had for padding was to match and divide to 4 case with 4x if statements, if the string is case 1 (seconds only): pad with 2x 0 zeroes, if case 2 (minutes only), pad with -X zeroes, etc