# PowerShell 5.1 casting to List doesnt work when you pass an array of one

Tags: powershell

Why does the last statement error when all of the others work?

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic;

$a = [List[int]](1, 2)    # list creates correctly
$b = [List[int]](@(1, 2)) # list creates correctly
$c = [List[int]](1)       # list creates correctly
$d = [List[int]](@(1))    # error: Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32".
```

Note that the issue only appears to happen in PowerShell 5.1.  In PowerShell Core it doesn't have any issues.

Comment: This is indeed a bug in the older version of windows PowerShell, you might workaround this with commands like: `$d = [List[int]]1` or: `$d = [List[int]](@(1) |% { $_ })` or `$d = [List[int]]([Int[]]@(1))`

Comment: @iRon That is a helpful workaround, thanks.  Do you have any info as to what the actual bug is, by chance?  Like is it PS unrolling behavior, explicit casting, implicit casting, something else?

Comment: I think @mklement0 filed an issue for this particular bug earlier this year (in the context of class `return` parameters in think), I can't find it now though :-/

Comment: @MathiasR.Jesse; [`#2208` v5 Regression: Casting object to more narrow generic collection fails with a single element, but not with two](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2208)

Comment: Additional workaround: `[List[int]]$($a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) has provided the crucial pointer:

- You're seeing a ***bug* in *Windows PowerShell*** that has [since been fixed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2208) in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), and because Windows PowerShell is no longer actively developed and receives security-critical fixes only, this won't be fixed.
- Specifically, casting from a *single*-element array whose *type isn't the same as the target list* fails, and `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), invariably creates `[object[]]` arrays.

  ```bash
  # UNEXPECTEDLY FAILS in Windows PowerShell:
  # Casting from a single-element array that isn't strongly typed
  # with the list's element type.
  [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]] @(1)
  ```

  - Note that other generic list types, such as [`` System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection-1), are *not* affected and neither is the non-generic `System.Collections.ArrayList` class, though the latter suffers from the *inverse* bug - see below.
- **Workarounds**:

  ```bash
  # Use a scalar
  [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]] 1

  # Use a strongly typed array
  [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]] [int[] @(1)

  # Also use a strongly typed array
  # if you're given an array $arr and don't know how many elements it has.
  [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]] [int[] $arr

  # Syntactically simpler, but slower alternative, using
  # $(...), the subexpression operator:
  [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]] $($arr)
  ```

  - The reason that `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) is slower (though it may not matter in practice) is that it *enumerates* `$arr` and then *collects the results*, in a *new* (`[object[]`) array, if `$arr` has *two or more elements*, otherwise a single-element array's only element is collected as-is (it is the latter behavior that makes `$(...)` effective as a workaround).

---

Note that there's a ***related bug* that also affects PowerShell (Core), up to at least v7.3.6** (current as of this writing):

- The [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList) class - which is [no longer recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist#remarks) - has the inverse problem, reported in [GitHub issue #11749](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11749):

  - Casting from a *scalar* unexpectedly breaks.

    ```bash
    # UNEXPECTEDLY FAILS up to at least PowerShell 7.3.6:
    # Casting from a scalar.
    [System.Collections.ArrayList] 1
    ```
- **Workaround**:

  ```bash
  # Use @(...)
  [System.Collections.ArrayList] @(1)
  ```

---

**Note:**

- That casting a *scalar* to a list type (e.g. `[System.Collections.Generic[int] 42` and `[int[]] 42`) works at all may be surprising.
- It is a testament to PowerShell's flexibility not just with respect to its automatic type conversions for *scalars*, but also its *unified handling of scalars and collections* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035802/45375) - which generally also extends to *casts* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63982452/45375).