# Where-object clause of Get-ChildItem only works when I use date functions in specific application

Tags: powershell

I have code to find files containing specific words that were written to the folder today. The following code works as expected:

```
##Define the directory to search
$Crmrpts = '\\1.1.1\crmrpts'
##Define the report names to search for. Full names not wildcard
$Values = 
@(
    'Customer',
    'Product',
    'Sales',
    'Returns',
    'Inventory'
)

##Gci the folder defined above looking for file names matching the reports to search for above
$Files = gci $Crmrpts '*.csv' | Where-Object {
    
    $v = $_.Name
    $t = $_.LastWriteTime.Date

    $Values | Where-Object { $v.Contains($_) -and $t.Equals((Get-Date).Date) }

}
```

The important variable here is `$t` and the section `$t.Equals((Get-Date).Date)`

Since I am looking for LastWriteTime.Date specifically, I assume I can change my search criteria to be a date, like so:

```
$Values | Where-Object { $v.Contains($_) -and $t.Equals("12/13/2020")
```

But this doesn't work. However, if I run another piece of independent code using the same components, it does work:

```
gci '\\1.1.1\crmrpts' | ? {$_.Name -like '*Customers*' -and $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq "12/13/2020"}
```

Why does the above line work, containing `$_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq "12/13/2020"` but that same piece of logic does not work in my original script above?

The only way I can get my original script to work for a date other than current date is like this:

```
$Values | Where-Object { $v.Contains($_) -and $t.Equals((Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .Net [DateTime.Equals()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.equals?view=net-5.0) method can only compare a datetime object with another datetime object.

That is why `$t.Equals("12/13/2020")` won't work, because you are telling the method to compare a datetime object to a string.

`$_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq "12/13/2020"` does work, because PowerShell conveniently converts the given date string to a datetime object before comparing.

Here, the conversion to a DateTime object works culture invariant as [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) commented.

However, if you have a different locale, like me (NL Dutch), you cannot rely on creating dates using the invariant "MM/dd/yyy" format all the time..
Especially, something like `Get-Date '12/13/2020'` will give me an exception because here the current locale settings (for me "dd/MM/yyyy") **are** used.

In short:

- always try and compare a datetime object to another datetime object
- don't assume that every machine in the world accepts the same date string format

Comment: Thanks for the info. I suppose using the .Net Equals() method bypasses or does not allow for the convenient implicit string conversion to a date that I am familiar with when simply piping Where-Object to Get-ChildItem. If I wanted to put the date to search in a variable, how would I construct that?

Comment: @sleven Well, there's lots of ways, like `$refDate = (Get-Date -Year 2020 -Month 12 -Day 13).Date` or `$refDate = [DateTime]::new(2020,12,13)` or if it is for yesterday `$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date` or `$refDate = [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1)`

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

**Use a `[datetime]` cast** to force the method argument to be of that type:

```
t.Equals([datetime] "12/13/2020")
```

---

> `$t.Equals("12/13/2020")`

As [Theo's helpful answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65290462/45375), the `[datetime]` type's `.Equals()` method only works as you intended if you pass a `[datetime]` instance - passing a *string representation* of a date is *not* automatically converted to `[datetime]`.<sup>[1]</sup>

By contrast, **PowerShell's [`-eq` *operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-eq) *does* perform implicit conversion of the RHS**, namely to the type of the LHS operand.

Therefore, `$_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq "12/13/2020"` is implicitly the same as:
`$_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq [datetime] "12/13/2020"` and that's why it worked.

Note that this implicit **conversion is culture-*invariant***; that is, it works the same irrespective of what culture is in effect in your session (as reflected in `$PSCulture` and by `Get-Culture`).

**PowerShell casts and automatic type conversions, including stringification in expandable strings (`"..."`), are generally culture-*invariant*** (based on [`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), which is based on the US-English culture).

**Notable exceptions**:

- Implicit type conversions in the context of **`-as`**, the [conditional type conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators), are unexpectedly culture-*sensitive*.

  - This inconsistency is discussed in [GitHub issue #8129](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8129).
- Implicit type conversions in the context of **binding to *cmdlet* parameters** are also unexpectedly culture-sensitive.

  - This inconsistency, which notably does *not* affect written-in-PowerShell functions and scripts - is discussed in [GitHub issue #6989](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6989); however, [a decision was made *not* to fix this](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3348#issuecomment-337799446) so as not to break backward compatibility.

Also note that PowerShell's *for-display output formatting* and the use of the **[`-f` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f)** (e.g., `'{0:N2}' -f 1.2`) are culture-*sensitive* by design.

For a **comprehensive discussion of culture invariance vs. sensitivity in PowerShell**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).

---

<sup>[1] Note that while PowerShell generally performs implicit type conversions also when calling *.NET methods*, in this case PowerShell's method-overload resolution algorithm chooses the `[object]` based `.ToEquals()` overload (`bool Equals(System.Object value)`), which therefore passes the string argument as-is - and `[datetime]` itself makes no attempt to perform automatic conversions, as is typical. It is *PowerShell* that provides automatic conversions in many cases, which is generally a great benefit, but has its pitfalls.</sup>