# In Powershell, how do I convert an array of PSObjects to an array of Strings?

Tags: powershell

My code is as follows:

```
    #Creating object with data name properties
$myData = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$myData | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $null
$myData | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Bot -Value $null
$myData | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PDD -Value $null
$myData | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SD -Value $null
$myData | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Dev -Value $null

#Empty ArrayList to Populate
$InputArray = @()

for ($i = 2; $i -le $rowMax; $i++)
{
    $objTemp = $myData | Select-Object *
    
    #Reading row data
    $objTemp.Name = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,1).Text
    $objTemp.Bot = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,2).Text
    $objTemp.PDD = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,3).Text
    $objTemp.SD = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,4).Text
    $objTemp.Dev = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,5).Text

    $InputArray += $objTemp
}

foreach ($i in $InputArray)
    {
        if ($i.Name -eq $CurrentName) {
                 #want to convert these name properties to strings
                 $Name = $i.Name
                 $Bot = $i.Bot
                 $PDD = $i.PDD
                 $Dev = $i.Dev
          
                               
        }  
     }
```

The code above builds the PSobject object with several name properties that are read in from an excel sheet. After that, I am reading in each psobject in $InputArray, and targeting the properties of the current array in that index.

The problem I'm running into is I need to convert the property values (Name, Bot, PDD, SD, Dev) into string values.

I've tried a few methods to no avail, any input would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[string] $Name = $i.Name` would store the stringified value of `$i.Name` in variable `$Name`, for instance - although it's surprising that that is needed, given that you're accessing a property named `.Text` on the Excel cell objects.

Generally, there are ***two* basic ways to *stringify* (convert a value to a string) in PowerShell**; assume the following two variable definitions in the examples below:

```bash
# Sample values to stringify.
$val = 1.2       # [double]
$coll = 42, 1.2  # array, containing [int] and [double]
```

- **With PowerShell custom logic**: culture-*invariant*, with additional logic for meaningfully stringifying *collections*, such as arrays:

  - Via a `[string]` *cast* or *type constraint*:

    ```bash
    [string] 1.2 # -> "1.2", irrespective of the current culture.

    # In combination with variables:
    $valAsString = [string] 1.2 # cast
    [string] $valAsString = 1.2 # type-constraint; auto-converts future 
                                # assignments to [string] too

    [string] $coll # -> "42 1.2", i.e. the space-concatenated list
                   #     of the (themselves stringified) elements.
    ```
  - Via an [*expandable* (interpolating) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), i.e. inside `"..."`:

    ```bash
    # Note: Only simple variable references as used here can *directly*
    #       be embedded in "..."; to embed *expressions or commands*,
    #       you must use $(...), the subexpression operator; e.g.:
    #         "$($val+1)" # -> "2.2"
    "$val"   # same as: [string] $val
    "$coll"  # same as: [string] $coll
    ```
- **Via the .NET type at hand**: potentially culture-*sensitive*:

  - Explicitly, via its `.ToString()` method:

    ```bash
    $val.ToString() # -> "1.2" in English cultures,
                    #    "1,2" in French, for instance

    $coll.ToString() # -> "System.Object[]", i.e. just the *type name*
    ```
  - Implicitly, via `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f):

    ```bash
    'val: {0}' -f $val # -> "val: 1.2" in English cultures,
                       #    "val: 1,2" in French, for instance
    ```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375) for more information.

Also note that PowerShell's flexible type conversions perform stringification *on demand*, e.g. when passing a non-string to a `[string]`-typed parameter.

---

As for **what you tried**:

Your code can be greatly simplified as follows; the source-code comments provide pointers, but explaining every optimization would be beyond the scope of this answer:

```bash
# Let PowerShell collect the loop output in an array for you,
$inputArray = 
  foreach ($i in 2..$rowMax) {
    # Construct and output a [pscustomobject] via a literal.
    # Note: If desired, you could apply [string] casts *here*; e.g.:
    #       Name = [string] $sheet.Cells.Item($i,1).Text      
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Name = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,1).Text
      Bot = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,2).Text
      PDD = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,3).Text
      SD = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,4).Text
      Dev = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,5).Text
    }
  }

# ...

foreach ($i in $InputArray) {
  if ($i.Name -eq $CurrentName) {
      # want to convert these name properties to strings
      [string] $Name = $i.Name
      [string] $Bot = $i.Bot
      [string] $PDD = $i.PDD
      [string] $Dev = $i.Dev
  }
  # ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, what a great response thank you so much. PSCustomObjects are awesome, that is so much simpler.  I was able to use the custom object successfully and now my script is in working shape. Thanks so much!