# DateTime Object culture gets lost between piping functions

Tags: powershell

I have two functions, `get-foo`:

```
Function get-foo{[PSCustomObject]@{Title = 'Some Title' ; CreationTime = [datetime]::Parse('31/01/2023')}}
```

and `set-foo`:

```
Function set-foo{  
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$Title,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$CreationTime

    )
    Begin{
        ([cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture).Name
    }
    Process{
        $CreationTime
    }
}
```

`get-foo` outputs a `en-gb` date, exactly the date format I want:

```
[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = 'en-GB' ; get-foo

Title      CreationTime
-----      ------------
Some Title 31/01/2023 00:00:00
```

When I pipe `get-foo` to `set-foo`, it converts the `[dateTime]` object into an American date:

```
get-foo|set-foo

# en-GB
# 01/31/2023 00:00:00
```

I tried to fix it by changing the following line in `set-foo`:

```
...
[Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$CreationTime = [datetime]::Parse($CreationTime)  # [datetime]::Parse() respects the sessions culture
        #[string]$CreationTime
...
```

Now I just get an error:

```
get-foo|set-foo
#ERROR: MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "String '' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

How to get `set-foo` to respect the sessions culture. I need to declare the `CreationTime` parameter as a `[string]`, otherwise `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` just becomes problematic to work with.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm trying to find a definitive reference, but I think your code is falling of PowerShell ignoring the "current" culture while performing datetime serialization when it binds the DateTime ```CreationTime``` property in the return value from ```get-foo``` to the string parameter ```$CreationTime``` in ```set-foo```. You can isolate this behaviour out with something as simple as ```[string][datetime]::utcnow``` vs ```[datetime]::utcnow.ToString()``` - if you've got an en-GB culture set you'll see ```01/12/2024 22:16:45``` and ```12/01/2024 22:19:04``` respectively.

Comment: @mclayton Yes, it does ignore the current culture, it's hardcoded to use invariant culture, basically doing `[System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertTo([datetime]::Now, [string], [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)`. I actually submitted an [issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/21053) yesterday for something similar cause got curious, luckily someone from the pwsh helped find the answer :P look for `ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute.cs` (link in the issue too)

Comment: To offer future readers a roadmap: the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77809530/45375) deserves its status for solving the problem stated in the question _as asked_.
The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77810222/45375) explains why the stated problem _isn't worth solving_ and provides background information. /cc @mclayton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you cannot / do not want to change the type of `$CreationDate` from `string` to `datetime` (which is what I would advise) but you want a string `datetime` in the `en-GB` format, then what you can do is create a class that implements the [`ArgumentTransformationAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.argumenttransformationattribute?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) that will `.ToString` using `en-GB` culture when a `datetime` is bound to `-CreationTime`:

```bash
class DateTransform : System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTransformationAttribute {
    static [cultureinfo] $culture = [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-GB')

    [Object] Transform(
        [System.Management.Automation.EngineIntrinsics] $engineIntrinsics,
        [Object] $inputData)
    {
        if ($inputData -is [datetime]) {
            return $inputData.ToString([DateTransform]::culture)
        }

        # else, if it's a string or other type, attempt coercion to string
        return $inputData
    }
}

function set-foo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string] $Title,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [DateTransform()]
        [string] $CreationTime
    )

    Begin {
        ([cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture).Name
    }
    Process {
        $CreationTime
    }
}

[PSCustomObject]@{
    Title        = 'Some Title'
    CreationTime = [datetime]::new(2023, 01, 31)
} | set-foo

# Outputs:
# en-US
# 31/01/2023 00:00:00
```

Comment: For ArgumentTransformationAttribute , the documentation recommends overloading toString() as well. Do you know what effect/benefit this would have on the above example?

Comment: @Blaisem to be honest, what they're saying in that documentation doesn't make any sense to me, they also state "If multiple transformations are defined on a parameter, they will be invoked in series", which doesn't make any sense either, why would you want to have more than 1 transformation when you can `switch` or chain `if` on `$inputData`. I would just ignore that recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

- Avoid *string* representations of non-string data such as date/time values as much as possible; if not possible, use the *invariant culture* to format values as strings.

  - Therefore, the best solution is to replace `[string] $CreationTime` with `[datetime] $CreationTime` in the declaration of your `set-foo` function.
- The *invariant culture* is what PowerShell *mostly* uses, notably whenever it converts a `[datetime]` value *to a string explicitly*, which happened in your case, and that is why you got the output you saw.

  - A simple example: `[string] (Get-Date)` yields something like `'01/12/2024 22:16:42'`, i.e. a *month-first* format, *irrespective of the current culture*.
  - By contrast, outputting a `[datetime]` instance *directly* (by default to the host/console) uses *culture-sensitive*, *for-display* formatting, as running `Get-Date` alone proves (as does running your `get-foo` command stand-alone).

---

**For *programmatic processing*, you should never rely on *culture-sensitive* representations**:

- **PowerShell *generally* tries to avoid such pitfalls by using the** - by definition culture-neutral and guaranteed-to-never-change - **[*invariant* culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) in conversions to and from *string* representations.**

  - This invariant culture is *based on* but not identical to the US-English culture, and therefore recognizes month-first date string formats such as `'1/12/2024'` for 1 December 2024; however, it *also* recognizes formats such as `'2024-12-1'`.
  - Its very purpose is to provide *stable, culture-independent* formatting for programmatic processing that is both culture-neutral and ensures long-term stability.
- ***Mistakenly*, PowerShell *strayed from this principle* in two cases**:

  - In from-string conversions **when binding to non-string parameters of *binary cmdlets***:

    - There, the **conversion is *unexpectedly culture-sensitive***; unfortunately, this problem will *not* be fixed, so as not to break backward compatibility - see [GitHub issue #6989](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6989)
    - Fortunately, **commands implemented *in PowerShell code* are *not* affected**.
  - Similarly, the **conversions performed by the [`-as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Operators) operator are unexpectedly *selectively* culture-sensitive**:

    - See [GitHub issue #8129](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8129) - no formal ruling has been made as to whether to fix this.
- For a **general overview of *culture sensitivity* vs. *culture invariance*** in PowerShell, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).

---

Thus, **in your own code**:

- **Avoid *string* representations of non-string data as much as possible**, in favor of specific data types such as [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime).
- **If string representations must be used, base them on the *invariant culture***.

  - PowerShell *generally* does that for you, notably:

    - in *to*-string conversions, e.g. when using [expandable (interpolating), double-quoted strings (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)
    - in *from* string conversions, if you use *casts* (e.g., `[datetime] '...'`)
  - Specifically - unless you expressly know that a given string was formatted based on the current culture - **avoid use of the *single-argument* overloads of `::Parse()` methods, in favor of the overloads that also have a [`System.IFormatProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IFormatProvider) parameter, to which you can pass `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture`** so as to ensure culture invariance (or, if needed, a [`[cultureinfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo) instance representing a specific culture).

    - In fact, this is precisely what PowerShell *casts* / type constraints do behind the scenes; e.g.:

      ```bash
      [datetime] '1/12/2024'
      ```

      - translates to:

        ```bash
         [datetime]::Parse('1/12/2024', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
        ```
- For the culture-sensitivity of a string representation **it matters whether *explicit* conversion to a string *by PowerShell* is involved** - in which case the ***invariant culture***'s representation is used - or whether **stringification happens *as part of PowerShell's default [for-display output formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview)*** - in which case the ***current* culture is used**, as exemplified by the following commands:

  ```bash
   # Explicit stringification by PowerShell: *invariant* culture
   # -> e.g. '01/12/2024 22:25:40'
   [string] (Get-Date)   # cast
   "$(Get-Date)"         # expandable string
   # Equivalent with a .NET method call:
   (Get-Date).ToString([cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)

   # Culture-specific stringifications:
   # Indirectly, by the output-formatting system.
   # -> e.g., with 'fr-FR' in effect: 'vendredi 12 janvier 2024 22:27:09'
   Get-Date 
   # Similar, with the argument-less .ToString() overload
   # -> e.g., with 'fr-FR in effect: '12/01/2024 22:27:09'
   (Get-Date).ToString()
  ```