# Date conversion issue in pipeline

Tags: powershell, datetime, azure-pipelines, datetime-format

I encountered a bizarre issue with date conversion. Everything is working as expected in my local PowerShell, but something goes wrong when the same code is running in a pipeline.
The goal is to capture the date from the title and convert it to a different format.

I have a title like:

```
$title = "Update 11-02-2024"
```

I am extracting the date from the title:

```
$date = ([regex]::Matches($title, '(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})')).Value
```

Converting the old date to a new format:

```
$newDate = Get-Date $date -UFormat "%B %d, %Y"
```

The new date is:

```
February 11, 2024
```

This is the right format for me, looks like it is working.
When the code is running via the pipeline the result is:

```
Update November 02, 2024
```

This is what the pipeline runs:

```
if ($itemTitle -match 'Update') {
                $date = ([regex]::Matches($itemTitle, '(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})')).Value
                $newDate = Get-Date $date -UFormat "%B %d, %Y"
                $newTitle = $itemTitle.Replace($Matches[0],"Dictionaries Update").Replace($date,$newDate)
                Write-host "The new title is: $newTitle"
            }
```

The pipeline runs a task that runs the script with the same code.
What am I missing?

Comment: Problem occurs because the pipeline is being executed on a runner machine with en-US default locale, so the default date format is `MM-dd-yyyy`. Use `[datetime]::ParseExact` to always use a specific format when parsing dates.

Comment: Thank you @Mathias
Can you tell me exactly where to put the change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This difference in parsing behavior likely occurs because the pipeline is being executed on a runner machine with `en-US` default locale, so the default date format is MM-dd-yyyy.

Use `[datetime]::ParseExact` to always use a specific format when parsing dates:

```
$newDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($date, 'dd-MM-yyyy', $null) |Get-Date -UFormat "%B %d, %Y"
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mathias
It will work even if the server is not an en-US? 
I am looking for a generic solution :)

Comment: @Bandit That's right, this will work regardless of locale/localization settings on the runner - now it'll always use `dd-MM-yyyy` as the expected input format no matter what

Comment: Ok thanks
What if the input will be changed?

Comment: @Bandit depends on the kind of change - it'll parse any string that describes a valid date in the expected format `dd-MM-yyyy`, but if you pass the string `"cats are magical"` it'll throw an error :) If the input format later changes to, say `yyyy-MM-dd`, all you have to do is update the format string in the code

Comment: Understand. So if the title will be changed to 02-11-2024 I will need to change the code to 
$newDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($date, 'MM-dd-yyyy', $null) |Get-Date -UFormat "%B %d, %Y"

Comment: @Bandit Not if `02-11-2024` describes the 2nd of November :)

Answer (score 1):

[Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77980915/45375) explains your problem and shows how to parse a *fixed* date format.

If you want to parse the date based on the *culture currently in effect* (as reported by [`Get-Culture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-culture), for instance), simply use the single-argument [`[dateTime]::Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.Parse) overload.

That is, if `<date>` in your `"Update <date>"` input string was created based on the current culture, say with `"Update " + (Get-Date -Format d)`,<sup>[1]</sup> you can parse and reformat it as follows:

```bash
[datetime]::Parse(
  (-split $title)[-1]
).ToString('MMMM dd, yyyy')
```

Or, if you prefer to format the resulting date via [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) `-UFormat`, preferring Unix-style formatting over .NET's [custom date and time format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) (which you can pass to `-Format`):

```bash
# Alternatively: ... -Format 'MMMM dd, yyyy' 
Get-Date ([datetime]::Parse((-split $title)[-1])) -UFormat '%B %d, %Y'
```

Note:

- `(-split $title)[-1]` extracts the last (-1) whitespace-separated token from your string, assumed to be the date string.
- In cases where you do have to specify the format explicitly, using [`[datetime]::ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ParseExact), pass `$null` to the 3rd parameter (`provider`) to request *current-culture* parsing, and [`[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) for *culture-invariant* parsing;<sup>[2]</sup> e.g.:

  ```bash
   # Parse based on the current culture.
   # Works in the US-English culture (en-US)
   # but not in the UK-English one (en-GB), for instance.
   [datetime]::ParseExact('November 02', 'M', $null)

   # Parse based on the invariant culture.
   # Always works, irrespective of what culture is in effect.
   [datetime]::ParseExact('November 02', 'M', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
  ```
- As an aside:

  - In contrast with a single-argument `[datetime]::Parse()` call, using a `[datetime]` PowerShell *cast* would perform culture-*invariant* parsing, in which case a US-style *month-first* date is assumed; e.g. `[datetime] '11-02-2024'` becomes 2 November 2024.
    In fact, such a cast is translated into the following call behind the scenes:

    ```bash
    # Equivalent of:
    #      [datetime] '11-02-2024'
    [datetime]::Parse('11-02-2024', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
    ```
  - For cross-culture scripting, PowerShell uses the [invariant culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) (which is based on, but distinct from the US-English culture) in many contexts - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375) for background information.

---

<sup>[1] However, note that `"Update $(Get-Date -Format d)"`, i.e. using PowerShell's *string interpolation* would result in a culture-*invariant* representation. See the last bullet point in this answer for background information.</sup>

<sup>[2] To request the rules of a *specific* culture (other than the current one), cast its name to [`[cultureinfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo); the following examples use `fr-FR`, the French culture as used in France:

`[datetime]::ParseExact('1 novembre', 'M', [cultureinfo] 'fr-FR')`.
For a list of all available cultures, use `Get-Culture -ListAvailable` in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), and `[cultureinfo]::GetCultures('SpecificCultures')` in *Windows PowerShell*.</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much 
Both answers are working. but I can accept only one :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Bandit. Understood re accepting, but you can always up-vote additional answers you found helpful (which I assume you have done here - thank you).