# Powershell is not recognising a date that has been formatted in datetime format

Tags: powershell, datetime, string-formatting

I am searching Splunk using powershell via API and get a list of data that contain dates (not in DateTime format).

The API call is performed by a Function that works fine and it works for the inital search which required the search and a start and end date/time.

Once the initial search completes I am looping over the results and performing sub-searches looking (in Splunk) looking for additional data from a different index.

I take the returned date and time (e.g. `16/02/2024 12:45:27`) split on the space and just return the date portion and then create two fields:

```
$EmailSearchStartdt = "$(($DateConversion).split(" ")[0]) 00:00:00" 
$EmailSearchEnddt = "$(($DateConversion).split(" ")[0]) 23:59:59"
```

This is all failing on the the two date fields. I'm taking the dates from the initial search and turning them back into datetime as so:

```
$EmailSearchStartdt = ([datetime]::ParseExact($EmailSearchStartdt,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-GB")))

$EmailSearchEnddt = ([datetime]::ParseExact($EmailSearchEnddt,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-GB")))
```

The problem is Powershell is reversing the day and month into US format (I'm in the UK with UK timezone settings etc) and when fed back into the function I get the following:

```
EmailSearchStartdt: 15/03/2024 00:00:00 (this is the string)
EmailSearchStartdt: **03/15**/2024 00:00:00 (this is after the parseexact)
EmailSearchEnddt: 15/03/2024 23:59:59 (this is the string)
EmailSearchEnddt: **03/15**/2024 23:59:59 (this is after the parseexact)
```

The result is Splunk finds nothing as the date has been reversed.

If I do the following:

```
$EmailSearchStartdt = get-date -date $EmailSearchStartdt -Format "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"
$EmailSearchEnddt = get-date -date $EmailSearchEnddt -Format "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

Splunk seems to accept this but if I try:

```
$EmailSearchStartdt = (get-date -date $EmailSearchStartdt -Format "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").adddays(-3)

$EmailSearchEnddt = (get-date -date $EmailSearchEnddt -Format "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").adddays(1)
```

I get: `Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'adddays'.`

So Powershell is seeing this as a string.

Ultimately the script is being invked with two dates that are strings but the function rejects this when its called internally with the sub-searches.

This has been literally driving me utterly mad so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `[datetime]::Parse('16/02/2024 12:45:27', [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-GB')).AddDays(1).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')` should work just fine

Comment: For the `get-date` with `-Format` options, keep in mind that `-Format` is only ever about **output** formats... it causes `get-date` to create a string instead of a real datetime object ... and **never** about the input format. This is why `AddDays()` is not available. [The `-date` argument also _only uses the system locale._](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.4#-date) If you need a different locale, use something from the .Net `DateTime::Parse()` family of methods.

Comment: But I need to know: is the `$DateConversion` variable actually a `DateTime` object already (it seems this might be the case) or is it a string?

Answer (score 2):

The core problem is that **[expandable (interpolating), double-quoted strings (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) in PowerShell use the [*invariant* culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) for stringifying non-string values** - irrespective of what culture is currently effect (as reported by `Get-Culture`), and the invariant culture is based on (but distinct from) the `en-US` culture with its ***month*-first date format**.

For instance, an expandable string such as `"$(Get-Date 1970-12-01)"` *always* yields `12/01/1970 00:00:00`, i.e. it reports the *month* first, which explains the results of your own attempts (e.g, `"$(($DateConversion).split(" ")[0]) 00:00:00"`).

By contrast, the `[datetime]` type's [`.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ToString) method (its parameter-less overload) uses the *current* culture, so that `(Get-Date 1970-12-01).ToString()`'s output *varies by culture*, and yields `01/12/1970 00:00:00` (day first) in the `en-GB` culture - however you may pass a cultural context *explicitly*, as shown below.

Therefore, it's **best to perform any calculations and modifications based on [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) instances *first*, and *then* create a string representation** explicitly based on the culture of interest (which may be the *current* one).

In your case, this means:

```bash
# Parse the input timestamp based on the given culture into
# [datetime] instances.
$culture = [cultureinfo] 'en-GB'
$format = 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'
$EmailSearchStartdt = [datetime]::ParseExact($EmailSearchStartdt, $format, $culture)
$EmailSearchEnddt = [datetime]::ParseExact($EmailSearchEnddt, $format, $culture)

# Modify these timestamps to refer to the start and end of the
# calendar day (.Date returns the start of the calendar day, 00:00:00)
$EmailSearchStartdt = $EmailSearchStartdt.Date
$EmailSearchEnddt = $EmailSearchStartdt.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1)

# Now stringify them as needed.
$outFormat = 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss'
$EmailSearchStartdt.ToString($outFormat, $culture)
$EmailSearchEnddt.ToString($outFormat, $culture)
```

Note that if your current culture is also the target culture, you can *omit* the `$culture` argument in the calls above.

Comment: Not that I doubt the accuracy of this, but I would love to find the documentation reference for that first assertion about interpolation using the invariant culture, but when I search the linked text for "invariant", "culture", "locale", "date", etc, I don't see anything.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, it's a good question to ask; PowerShell's documentation often lacks key concepts (though things are improving since the docs were open-sourced). For a _de facto_ description of PowerShell's behavior with respect to culture-sensitivity in string operations, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375). For an attempt to amend the documentation, see [GitHub docs issue #10953](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/10953).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the initial `$(($DateConversion))` interpolation is not creating the result you expect. Everything else proceeds from there.

An important thing to understand here is Powershell (and .Net) have an internal `DateTime` type *that is not built using strings at all*. Because of the initial formatting issue, **I suspect the `$DateConversion` variable already uses this `DateTime` type to store the correct value**, and you're doing a lot of extra work for nothing.

But before I come to the solution, there are a few things to note:

For the `get-date` cmdlet, keep in mind the `-Format` argument is only ever about **output** formats — it causes `get-date` to create a `string` instead of a real `DateTime` object — and **never** about the input format. This is why `AddDays()` is not available: you have a `string` instead of a `DateTime`. [The `-date` argument also *only uses the system (not invariant) locale.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.4#-date) If you need a different locale, use something from the .Net `DateTime::Parse()` family of methods.

But really, the correct way to handle a range for a single day is **NOT** to check from `00:00:00` to `11:59:59` of that day. Rather, you should use a half-open range with an exclusive upper boundary for the first instant (`00:00:00`) of *the next day*. Furthermore, the correct way to truncate a value back to the beginning (or end) of the day is **NOT** to output to a string and then reparse with `00:00:00` (or `11:59:59`) as the time value.

As you are discovering, *thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, converting between strings and dates is always a much more complicated process than we expect*, which makes it slower and more error-prone than we'd like. Instead, **avoid using string manipulation to edit dates; keep the values as `DateTime` objects for as long as possible, and use the methods and properties provided by the type**... for example, the `.Date` property.

Put it all together and you should be able to reduce this all down to this:

```
$EmailSearchStartdt = $DateConversion.Date
$EmailSearchEnddt = $DateConversion.Date.AddDays(1)
```

Keeping in mind the search itself should now also be changed to use an exclusive upper boundary (`<`/`-lt` instead of `<=`/`-le`). If this change is not possible, you can still likely reduce it to this:

```
$EmailSearchStartdt = $DateConversion.Date
$EmailSearchEnddt = $DateConversion.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1)
```

Which will also protect you against missing messages that might be sent during the last second of the day.

If you still need these values as strings to send to Splunk, you can use `.ToString()` with whatever cultural option you want. But again: I said, "If", and you should avoid this if you can. It's better to keep these things as `DateTime` objects for as long as you possibly can.

And now we have code that is much shorter, more correct, less susceptible to odd cultural issues, and (as a bonus) faster.

Finally, there is possibility I'm wrong about the `$DateConversion` data type. If this is true, the best option is **still** to parse to a  `DateTime` object initially, which you can even re-assign back to this same variable. And then you can still use the code I recommended to create your final date range.

**The important thing is to train yourself to stop thinking about date variables in terms of strings.**

Comment: Speaking of deficiencies in the PowerShell documentation: As of this writing, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.4#-date is not only incorrect - it is the _current thread's_ culture (locale) that matters, which defaults to the _current user's_  - not the _system's_  - culture/locale, it crucially also neglects to point out that - for the sake of consistency - it _shouldn't_ use the thread's locale, and that the fact that it does is an _accident_, which wasn't corrected lest backward compatibility be broken.

Comment: See [GitHub issue #6989](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6989) - which also notes that cmdlet-_like_ advanced functions _do_ use the invariant culture, only _binary cmdlets_ do not.

Comment: As for amending the docs: see [GitHub docs issue #10954](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/10954)